# Converting an array of objects to an array of their primitive types

Tags: java, arrays, primitive-types

If you have an array of Java objects which have a primitive type (for example Byte, Integer, Char, etc).  Is there a neat way I can convert it into an array of the primitive type?  In particular can this be done without having to create a new array and loop through the contents.

So for example, given

```
Integer[] array
```

what is the neatest way to convert this into

```
int[] intArray
```

Unfortunately, this is something we have to do quite frequently when interfacing between Hibernate and some third party libraries over which we have no control.  It seems this would be a quite common operation so I would be surprised if there's no shortcut.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing in the Java platform that does this. Btw, you also need to explicitly handle `null` elements in the `Integer[]` array (what `int` are you going to use for those?).

Comment: Good point about the nulls.  For my purposes I would have accepted an exception being thrown if one of the entries is null, the same way an NullPointerException is thrown when you unbox an object.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate with Java 8, see [Alex's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24720136/305973).

Answer (score 93):

Once again, [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) is your friend. They provide [ArrayUtils.toPrimitive()](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Integer[])) which does exactly what you need. You can specify how you want to handle nulls.

Answer (score 81):

With [streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) introduced in Java 8 this can be done:

```
int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(array).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

However, there are currently only primitive streams for `int`, `long` and `double`. If you need to convert to another primitive type such as `byte` the shortest way without an external library is this:

```
byte[] byteArray = new byte[array.length];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) byteArray[i] = array[i];
```

Or the for loop can be replaced with a stream if you want:

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(i -> byteArray[i] = array[i]);
```

All of these will throw a `NullPointerException` if any of your elements are `null`.

Comment: Instead of `Integer::intValue`, you can also use `i -> i` (which uses unboxing).

Comment: @robinst And unboxing is the compiler calling `Integer::intValue` for you, so why create a new lambda, when the method is readily available?

Comment: @Andreas Just listing another option, which one you choose is a question of code style/personal preference. I also microbenchmarked (using JMH) the two approaches, and they have the same performance.

Comment: Using the first code snippet posted was giving me a "Can't use non-static method in static context" error so I instead did:

`int[] ints = Arrays.stream(objects).mapToInt(i -> Integer.parseInt(i.toString())).toArray();`

Hope this is helpful for anyone with the same issue. And if anyone knows a better way please let me know.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer nowadays. Thanks Alex.

Comment: `Arrays.setAll(unboxed, i -> boxed[i]);` is a nice alternative to the for loop from my perspective.

Comment: @BjörnZurmaar `setAll` only has overloads for the same primitive types as streams, so you couldn't use it for `byte`, but you could do `Arrays.setAll(array, i -> byteArray[i] = array[i])` which will also write to the original array.

Answer (score 27):

Using [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
int[] intArray = Ints.toArray(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Documentation:

- [`Arrays.asList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) (Core API)
- [`Ints.toArray`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray-java.util.Collection-) (Guava)

Answer (score 3):

> In particular can this be done without having to create a new array and loop through the contents.

You can't convert an array of Integer to int (i.e. you can't change the type of the elements of an array) in Java. So you either must create a new int[] array and copy the value of the Integer objects into it or you can use an adapter:

```
class IntAdapter {
    private Integer[] array;
    public IntAdapter (Integer[] array) { this.array = array; }
    public int get (int index) { return array[index].intValue(); }
}
```

This can make your code a little more readable and the IntAdapter object will only consume a few bytes of memory. The big advantage of an adapter is that you can handle special cases here:

```
class IntAdapter {
    private Integer[] array;
    public int nullValue = 0;
    public IntAdapter (Integer[] array) { this.array = array; }
    public int get (int index) { 
        return array[index] == null ? nullValue : array[index].intValue();
    }
}
```

Another solution is to use [Commons Primitives](http://commons.apache.org/primitives/) which contains lots of predefined adapters. In your case, have a look at [ListIntList](http://commons.apache.org/primitives/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/primitives/adapters/ListIntList.html).

Answer (score 2):

Or just do it the easy way if you gonna do it only once. But you haven't talked about Integer!=null case.

```
    //array is the Integer array
    int[] array2 = new int[array.length];
    int i=0;
    for (Integer integer : array) {
        array2[i] = integer.intValue();
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

using [Dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar) is simple as:

```
Integer[] array = ...;
int[] primitiveArray = $(array).toIntArray();
```

Comment: This does not appear to be Java, at least not Java 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: @LorDalCol Dollar is actually a Java library

Comment: It is possible to name a Java method `$`! I don’t think it’s encouraged, though…

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic solution for all primitive types

```
/**
 * Convert Collection to equivalent array of primitive type
 * @param <S> [in] Object type of source collection
 * @param tcls [in] class of the primitive element
 * @param q [in] source collection
 * @return Equivalent Array of tcls-elements, requires cast to "tcls"[]
 */
public static <S> Object asPrimitiveArray(Class<?> tcls, Collection<S> q)
{
    int n = q.size();
    Object res = Array.newInstance(tcls, n);
    Iterator<S> i = q.iterator();
    int j = 0;
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        Array.set(res, j++, i.next());
    }
    return res;
}

/**
 * Convert Object array to equivalent array of primitive type
 * @param <S> [in] Object type of source array
 * @param tcls [in] class of the primitive element
 * @param s [in] source array
 * @return Equivalent Array of tcls-elements, requires cast to "tcls"[]
 */
public static <S> Object asPrimitiveArray(Class<?> tcls, S[] s)
{
    return asPrimitiveArray(tcls, Arrays.asList(s));
}
```

For Integer to int conversion

```
Integer[] a = ...
int[] t = (int[]) asPrimitiveArray(int.class, a);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `Stream` API to create primitive type arrays from their boxed object counterparts.

For `Character[]` array conversion to `char[]`, using an accordingly size-allocated custom `Collector`, with `Supplier<CharBuffer>`, `BiConsumer<CharBuffer, Character>` accumulator, `BinaryOperator<CharBuffer>` combiner and `Function<CharBuffer, char[]>` finisher), as following will work:

```
Collector<Character, CharBuffer, char[]> charArrayCollector = Collector.of(
  () -> CharBuffer.allocate(95), 
  CharBuffer::put, 
  CharBuffer::put, 
  CharBuffer::array
);
```

It supplies the `CharBuffer` for the printable ASCII chars, accumulating each streamed Character into a CharBuffer instance, combining parallelized processing results from multiple CharBuffer instances in correct order and finally builds the desired `char[]` array from the accumulated and combined results, after all threads have finished.

First, we're creating a `Character[]` test array from the standard printable ASCII set, by utilizing the `int` values from an `IntStream`, by iterating the ASCII range and mapping each value into a Character `Stream`, after casting them to `char` primitives and converting those to `Character` objects:

```
Character[] asciiCharacters = IntStream.range(32, 127)
  .mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf((char)i))
  .toArray(Character[]::new);
```

Now, we simply need to create a `Stream` of Characters from the `Character` array, which then can be collected into a `char[]` array, by the custom Collector.

```
char[] asciiChars = Stream.of(asciiCharacters ).collect(charArrayCollector);
```

This works for other `Number` types accordingly:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { Byte.MIN_VALUE, -1 , 0, 1, Byte.MAX_VALUE };
Byte[] boxedBytes = IntStream.range(0, bytes.length)
  .mapToObj(i -> bytes[i])
  .toArray(Byte[]::new);
byte[] collectedBytes = Stream.of(boxedBytes).collect(
  Collector.of(
    () -> ByteBuffer.allocate(boxedBytes.length), 
    ByteBuffer::put, 
    ByteBuffer::put, 
    ByteBuffer::array
  )
);

short[] shorts = new short[] { Short.MIN_VALUE, -1, 0, 1, Short.MAX_VALUE };
Short[] boxedShorts = IntStream.range(0, shorts.length)
  .mapToObj(i -> shorts[i])
  .toArray(Short[]::new);
short[] collectedShorts = Stream.of(boxedShorts).collect(
  Collector.of(
    () -> ShortBuffer.allocate(boxedShorts .length), 
    ShortBuffer::put, 
    ShortBuffer::put, 
    ShortBuffer::array
  )
);

float[] floats = new float[] { Float.MIN_VALUE, -1.0f, 0f, 1.0f, Float.MAX_VALUE };
Float[] boxedFLoats = IntStream.range(0, floats.length)
  .mapToObj(i -> floats[i])
  .toArray(Float[]::new);
float[] collectedFloats = Stream.of(boxedFLoats).collect(
  Collector.of(
    () -> FloatBuffer.allocate(boxedFLoats.length), 
    FloatBuffer::put, 
    FloatBuffer::put, 
    FloatBuffer::array
  )
);
```

The primitive types, for which `Stream` API supports it, can be converted a bit easier:

```
int[] ints = new int[] { Integer.MIN_VALUE, -1, 0, 1, Integer.MAX_VALUE };
Integer[] integers = IntStream.of(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
int[] collectedInts = Stream.of(integers).collect(
  Collector.of(
    () -> IntBuffer.allocate(integers.length), 
    IntBuffer::put, 
    IntBuffer::put, 
    IntBuffer::array
  )
);

long[] longs = new long[] { Long.MIN_VALUE, -1l, 0l, 1l, Long.MAX_VALUE };
Long[] boxedLongs = LongStream.of(longs).boxed().toArray(Long[]::new);
long[] collectedLongs = Stream.of(boxedLongs ).collect(
  Collector.of(
    () -> LongBuffer.allocate(boxedLongs .length), 
    LongBuffer::put, 
    LongBuffer::put, 
    LongBuffer::array
  )
);

double[] doubles = new double[] { Double.MIN_VALUE, -1.0, 0, 1.0, Double.MAX_VALUE };
Double[] boxedDoubles = DoubleStream.of(doubles)
  .boxed()
  .toArray(Double[]::new);
double[] collectedDoubles = Stream.of(boxedDoubles).collect(
  Collector.of(
    () -> DoubleBuffer.allocate(boxedDoubles.length), 
    DoubleBuffer::put, 
    DoubleBuffer::put, 
    DoubleBuffer::array
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, we can convert Arrays of Objects to primitive, please refer below code.
Java 8 is awesome at to learn java 8 skills in more detail I have got one youtube channel.

https://www.youtube.com/@thefullstackguy
Happy Learning :)

```
private static int[] reverseJava8(int[] arr) {
    Object[] objects = Arrays.stream(arr)
            .boxed()
            .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
            .toArray();
    return Arrays.stream(objects).mapToInt(i -> (int) i).toArray();

}
```

Comment: Why the reversing sort? OP didn't ask for that.