# How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, primitive-types

I'm trying to convert an ArrayList containing Integer objects to primitive int[] with the following piece of code, but it is throwing compile time error. Is it possible to convert in Java?

```
List<Integer> x =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
int[] n = (int[])x.toArray(int[x.size()]);
```

Comment: If you don't need primitive ints, you can use:
    `List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
    `Integer[] n = x.toArray(new Integer[0]);`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting an array of objects to an array of their primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564392/converting-an-array-of-objects-to-an-array-of-their-primitive-types)

Comment: @cellepo That question is about converting between an Object and primitive array, this is about converting between an ArrayList and primitive array

Answer (score 266, accepted):

You can convert, but I don't think there's anything built in to do it automatically:

```
public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
{
    int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
    for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

(Note that this will throw a NullPointerException if either `integers` or any element within it is `null`.)

EDIT: As per comments, you may want to use the list iterator to avoid nasty costs with lists such as `LinkedList`:

```
public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
{
    int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = integers.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: It might be better to iterate using the List's iterator (with for each) so as to avoid performance hits on lists whose access is not O(1).

Comment: You can also utilize the fact the ArrayList implements Iterable (via Collection inheritance) and do: for(int n : integer) { ret[counter++] = n; } ... and initialize int counter = 0;

Comment: much easier now in Java8: `integers.stream().mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).toArray`

Answer (score 413):

If you are using [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8) there's also another way to do this.

```
int[] arr = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

What it does is:

- getting a `Stream<Integer>` from the list
- obtaining an `IntStream` by mapping each element to itself (identity function), unboxing the `int` value hold by each `Integer` object (done automatically since Java 5)
- getting the array of `int` by calling `toArray`

You could also explicitly call `intValue` via a method reference, i.e:

```
int[] arr = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

It's also worth mentioning that you could get a `NullPointerException` if you have any `null` reference in the list. This could be easily avoided by adding a filtering condition to the stream pipeline like this:

```
                       //.filter(Objects::nonNull) also works
int[] arr = list.stream().filter(i -> i != null).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Example:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
int[] arr = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray(); //[1, 2, 3, 4]

list.set(1, null); //[1, null, 3, 4]
arr = list.stream().filter(i -> i != null).mapToInt(i -> i).toArray(); //[1, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I see this can be used for `double` types; are there no equivalent for `float` types?

Answer (score 87):

## Google Guava

[Google Guava](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) provides a neat way to do this by calling [`Ints.toArray`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray(java.util.Collection)).

```
List<Integer> list = ...;
int[] values = Ints.toArray(list);
```

Answer (score 68):

Apache Commons has a ArrayUtils class, which has a method toPrimitive() that does exactly this.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils;
...
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(new Integer(1));
    list.add(new Integer(2));
    int[] intArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(list.toArray(new Integer[0]));
```

However, as Jon showed, it is pretty easy to do this by yourself instead of using external libraries.

Comment: Note that this approach will make two complete copies of the sequence:  one Integer[] created by toArray, and one int[] created inside toPrimitive.  The other answer from Jon only creates and fills one array.  Something to consider if you have large lists, and performance is important.

Comment: I measured performance using ArrayUtils vs pure java and on small lists (<25 elements) pure java is more than 100 times faster. For 3k elements pure java is still almost 2 times faster... (ArrayList<Integer> --> int[])

Comment: @paraquat & Oskar Lund that is not actually correct. Yes, the code provided will create two arrays, but this **approach** does not. The problem in this code here is the use of a zero length array as the argument. The [ArrayList.toArray source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.toArray%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) shows that if the contents will fit, the original array will be used. I think in a fair comparison you'll find this method to be as efficient (if not more) and, of course, less code to maintain.

Comment: Waht is the purpose of new Integer[0]?

Comment: @AdamHughes I believe it is to give a hint to `toArray` of which type of array to create

Answer (score 43):

I believe iterating using the List's iterator is a better idea, as `list.get(i)` can have poor performance depending on the List implementation:

```
private int[] buildIntArray(List<Integer> integers) {
    int[] ints = new int[integers.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer n : integers) {
        ints[i++] = n;
    }
    return ints;
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Java 8:

```
int[] intArr = Arrays.stream(integerList).mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
```

Answer (score 11):

### Arrays.setAll()

```
    List<Integer> x = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(7, 9, 13));
    int[] n = new int[x.size()];
    Arrays.setAll(n, x::get);

    System.out.println("Array of primitive ints: " + Arrays.toString(n));
```

Output:

> Array of primitive ints: [7, 9, 13]

The same works for an array of `long` or `double`, but not for arrays of `boolean`, `char`, `byte`, `short` or `float`. If you’ve got a really huge list, there’s even a `parallelSetAll` method that you may use instead.

To me this is good and elgant enough that I wouldn’t want to get an external library nor use streams for it.

**Documentation link:** [`Arrays.setAll(int[], IntUnaryOperator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#setAll(int%5B%5D,java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator))

Answer (score 7):

using [Dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar) should be quite simple:

```
List<Integer> list = $(5).toList(); // the list 0, 1, 2, 3, 4  
int[] array = $($(list).toArray()).toIntArray();
```

I'm planning to improve the DSL in order to remove the intermediate `toArray()` call

Answer (score 7):

This works nice for me :)

Found at https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-list-integer-array-int/

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

class ListUtil
{
    // Program to convert list of integer to array of int in Java
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

        int[] primitive = list.stream()
                            .mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
                            .toArray();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(primitive));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

**Arrays.setAll()** will work for most scenarios:

1. Integer List to primitive int array:

   ```
   public static int[] convert(final List<Integer> list)
   {
      final int[] out = new int[list.size()];
      Arrays.setAll(out, list::get);
      return out;
   }
   ```
2. Integer List (made of Strings) to primitive int array:

   ```
   public static int[] convert(final List<String> list)
   {
      final int[] out = new int[list.size()];
      Arrays.setAll(out, i -> Integer.parseInt(list.get(i)));
      return out;
   }
   ```
3. Integer array to primitive int array:

   ```
   public static int[] convert(final Integer[] array)
   {
      final int[] out = new int[array.length];
      Arrays.setAll(out, i -> array[i]);
      return out;
   }
   ```
4. Primitive int array to Integer array:

   ```
   public static Integer[] convert(final int[] array)
   {
      final Integer[] out = new Integer[array.length];
      Arrays.setAll(out, i -> array[i]);
      return out;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 5):

Java 8

```
int[] array = list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();

OR 

int[] array = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Comment: Your answer is a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23688547/6367213). Please delete your post and try to avoid doing that in the future.

Answer (score 4):

It bewilders me that we encourage one-off custom methods whenever a perfectly good, well used library like Apache Commons has solved the problem already.  Though the solution is trivial if not absurd, it is irresponsible to encourage such a behavior due to long term maintenance and accessibility.

Just go with [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Integer%5B%5D,%20int%29)

Comment: I do agree with the previous commenter. Not only do you drag in Apache Commons, but it easily translates into a large set of transitive dependencies that also need to be dragged in. Recently I could remove an amazing # of dependencies by replacing one line of code :-( Dependencies are costly and writing basic code like this is good practice

Comment: Agreed with @PeterKriens.  If anything, the fault is in Java for not supporting simple conversions like this in its standard data types

Answer (score 3):

If you're using [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can use the `collectInt()` method to switch from an object container to a primitive int container.

```
List<Integer> integers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
MutableIntList intList =
  ListAdapter.adapt(integers).collectInt(i -> i);
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, intList.toArray());
```

If you can convert your `ArrayList` to a `FastList`, you can get rid of the adapter.

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(
  new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
  Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .collectInt(i -> i).toArray());
```

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply copy it to an array:

```
int[] arr = new int[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    arr[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Not too fancy; but, hey, it works...

Answer (score 1):

Next lines you can find convertion from int[] -> List -> int[]

```
   private static int[] convert(int[] arr) {
        List<Integer> myList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for(int number:arr){
               myList.add(number);
            }
        }
        int[] myArray=new int[myList.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
           myArray[i]=myList.get(i);
        }
        return myArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code segment is working for me, try this:

```
Integer[] arr = x.toArray(new Integer[x.size()]);
```

Worth to mention ArrayList should be declared like this:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hello just a gentle reminder that OP wants a primitive array not an Object array.

Comment: Primitive int not wrapper Integer!

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use java stream for this task if time is critical for your task**

It is slower than using for-each loop. Use the same as:

```
    List<Integer> modes = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] m = new int[modes.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        m[i] = modes.get(i);
    }
```

You can measure it with ***jmh***

Answer (score -1):

A very simple one-line solution is:

```
Integer[] i = arrlist.stream().toArray(Integer[]::new);
```

Comment: op said primitive array meaning int[] not the Integer[] wrapper object, lol

Answer (score -4):

```
   List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);

    int[] result = null;
    StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (Object o : list) {
        strBuffer.append(o);
        result = new int[] { Integer.parseInt(strBuffer.toString()) };
        for (Integer i : result) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        strBuffer.delete(0, strBuffer.length());
    }
```

Comment: This answer does not work, it returns an array with a single element instead of multiple elements.

Comment: Why use a StringBuffer? Why convert the Integer to a String and then to an Integer and then to an int and then to an Integer again? Why use an array with a single element in it, and why loop over that single-element array when it contains just one element? Why cast the Integers to Objects in the outer loop? There are so many questions here. Is @CodeMadness just a troll account?

Answer (score -7):

```
Integer[] arr = (Integer[]) x.toArray(new Integer[x.size()]);
```

access `arr` like normal `int[]`.

Comment: this does not answer the question, the question was about converting to primitive type (int)