# Cast ArrayList of wrappers to corresponding array of primitives

Tags: java, casting, arraylist

I use an *ArrayList* with the wrapper class *Short*.
After adding some values I want to get the primitive array, but it seems that there is no way with the function `toArray(Object[] array)`, because it need an *Array* with the wrapper class.

Is there another way without using a for or anything like that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Apache Commons / Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) has a class [ArrayUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28short%5B%5D%29) that defines these methods.

- All methods called `toObject()` convert from primitive array to wrapper array.
- All called `toPrimitive()` convert from wrapper object array to primitive array

I think, you need [`ArrayUtils's`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toObject%28short%5B%5D%29) [`toPrimitive()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Short[]))

```
public static short[] toPrimitive(Short[] array)
```

> Converts an array of object Shorts to primitives.

Answer (score 2):

Try `org.apache.commons.lang.ArrayUtils`'s `toPrimitive(...)` method.

Comment: Just be careful with this, since you are **copying** array two times: first time with `toArray()` and second time with `toPrimitive()`. None of them returns underlying array.

Answer (score 1):

You can fill the array yourself:

```
ArrayList<Short> shorts = ...;
short shortArray[] = new short[shorts.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < shorts.size(); i++)
   shortArray[i] = shorts.get(i);
```

Notice that I exploit autoboxing in the assignment line.

Comment: You could use a library as others suggest, but that seems a bit of an overkill to avoid writing three lines of code.

Comment: He wanted a solution *without* a for loop.

Comment: @phlogratos: He doesn't state that anywhere. Also, a library would of course use a for loop in the same way as above, so the loop is just pushed into some library function.

Comment: He wrote: `Is there another way without using a for or anything like that?`

Comment: Ok, I must have misread that sentence. The answer to his question is basically that he needs a for loop, either in a library function or written directly.

Comment: Because it is opensource, you can take the parts you need. :)