# java String on repetition of alphabets

Tags: java, string

I am a java noob and I have particular problem.
Let us consider a String which multipe repetition of alphabets in it :

```
String a="AAABBBAACCBBDD"
```

I have tried this multiple times with `for` and `charAt`. 
Expected output:

```
"ABCD"
```

Is there any builtin function for this operation and any ideas to get output ?

Comment: What code did you use the time you got closest to a solution?

Comment: Please post what you have so far. We'd like to see some effort on your part.

Comment: I do not understand the problem. Just iterate over the characters and remember those you found so far... e.g. by using a Set

Comment: by using inbult     `String b=a.charAt(0)` then looping with for by String length . `for(int i=0;i<=((a.length())-1);i++)` then followed by     if to compare with charAt `if((a.charAt(i))!=(b.charAt(i))` from then.  i am confused

Comment: @home: what if i got String "a" from user by Scanner statement

Comment: Read the JavaDocs - `String#charAt(int)` does not even return a `String`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do something like

```
public static String dedup(String text) {
    Set<Character> seen = new LinkedHashSet<Character>();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : text.toCharArray())
        if (seen.add(c))
            sb.append(c);
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: +1; but if the alphabet was `CBAAABBBAACCBBDD`, the linked set will fail. Depending on the requirements it might be necessary to sort the final set...

Comment: @home How will the linked set fail? This will print `CBAD` in order of appearance.

Comment: that's just what I meant by 'requirements' - the output might have to be provided in lexicographical/natural order (`ABCD` instead of  `CBAD`).

Comment: @all: what do blue color text mean ?

Comment: @home I doesn't see how than means the linked set will fail.

Comment: @tam_ubuuser In the code it means classes in Java (i.e. words which start with an upper case letter) Everywhere else its a web page hyper link you can click on.  ;)

Comment: @Peter: ok, 'fail' might be the wrong term (of course it won't fail, apologies), I just meant that it might not be necessary to prefer a LinkedHashSet (again depends on requirements).

Answer (score 4):

You can iterate over the characters of the string to build up a set of the unique characters:

```
String a = "AAABBBAACCBBDD";
Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<String>();
for (char c : a.toCharArray())
{
    charSet.add(c);
}
```

Then you can convert the set to a list and sort it for display/`toString()` purposes:

```
List<Character> uniqueCharList = new ArrayList<Character>(charSet);
Collections.sort(uniqueCharList);

// Convert List<Character> to char[]
// see http://stackoverflow.com/q/6649100/139010 for a more concise library call
char[] uniqueCharArray = new char[uniqueCharList.size()];
for (int i=0; i<uniqueCharArray.length; i++)
{
    uniqueCharArray[i] = uniqueCharList.get(i);
}

String result = new String(uniqueCharArray);
```

Comment: I would use LinkedHashSet to preserve order. ;)

Comment: That does not provide lexicographic ordering. Better to just sort when you're all done, using a `List`, IMO.

Comment: Its not clear if the OP wants order of appearance or ASCIIbetical order.

Comment: Then you can convert the set to a list and sort it for display/toString() purposes.
 how to do that?

Answer (score -2):

You dont need list or set to this. Just String to store everything. I hope this have not bugs in it.

```
String result = "";
for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) 
    if(!result.contains(a[i])) {
           result += a[i];          
    }
```

Comment: -1. This will have _terrible_ asymptotic runtime performance. Each call to `String#contains()` is _O(n)_, and string concatenation in a loop is _O(n²)_.

Comment: It works in theory, but what if the string was extremely long? Reconsider your approach.