# How to pass a byte[] to this function

Tags: java

I have a function with this signature:

```
void insert(T[] thearray);
```

And I have a byte array like this:

```
byte[] value = new byte[4096];
```

But if I call function like this:

cb.insert(value);

I get a error:

```
The method insert(Byte) in the type CircularBuffer<Byte> is not applicable for the arguments (byte[])
```

CircularBuffer is the class with the insert method.

I instantiate CircularBuffer like this:

```
CircularBuffer<Byte> cb = new CircularBuffer<Byte>(4096);
```

How can I pass the value to this insert function?

To be clear, the CircularBuffer class is declared like this:

```
public class CircularBuffer<T>

public CircularBuffer(int size) //ctor
```

More details if you need:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/22826/circular-buffer-implementation-for-buffering-tcp-socket-messages

EDIT in the end I decided for efficiency reasons to create a specialised ByteCircularBuffer.  - using byte.  This area of primitive type to object type, eg byte -> Byte is confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Byte` is quite different from `byte`. Either convert array of bytes to array of Bytes (this requires lot of time and memory), or write new class `ByteCircularBuffer` (take `CircularBuffer<T>` and replace `T` with `byte`).

Comment: I tried this: class ByteCircularBuffer extends CircularBuffer<byte> { }  but then get errors: Multiple markers at this line. - Syntax error on token "byte", Dimensions expected after this token. - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)

Comment: Yup.  You can't have `ByteCircularBuffer` extend `CircularBuffer`.  You have to make an entirely separate class.

Answer (score 6):

A `byte[]` is not a `Byte[]`.  You will need to explicitly convert one to the other first.

See e.g. *[Cast ArrayList of wrappers to corresponding array of primitives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649100/cast-wrapper-array-to-corresponding-primitive-array)* for possible ways to do this.

Comment: I don't want to copy a possibly large array.  I think the link copies.  I also don't want to have to use a third party class.

Comment: @user619818: You don't really have a choice, other than modifying your CircularBuffer class.

Comment: How would I modify CircularBuffer?

Comment: @user619818: I don't know, I haven't looked at it!