# Most efficient way to convert InputStream into byte[]?

Tags: java, inputstream

```
ChannelBufferInputStream responseStream = (ChannelBufferInputStream) response.getBodyAsStream();
ArrayList<Byte> arrayList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
try {
    while (responseStream.available() > 0) {
        arrayList.add(responseStream.readByte());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return internalServerError();
}
Iterator<Byte> iterator = arrayList.iterator();
byte[] bytes = new byte[arrayList.size()];
int i = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    bytes[i++] = iterator.next();
}
```

This code is called on every page load of my web app. It seems to be running pretty fast, but is there anything that could make this run faster?

Edit - Updated using byte array output stream

```
ChannelBufferInputStream responseStream = (ChannelBufferInputStream) response.getBodyAsStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    int read = responseStream.read();
    while (read != -1) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(read);
        read = responseStream.read();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return internalServerError();
}
byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
return ok(bytes).as(response.getHeader("Content-type"));
```

Edit - Benchmark test code

```
ChannelBufferInputStream responseStream = (ChannelBufferInputStream) response.getBodyAsStream();
long t1 = System.nanoTime();

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    int read = responseStream.read();
    while (read != -1) {
        byteArrayOutputStream.write(read);
        read = responseStream.read();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return internalServerError();
}
byte[] bytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

long t2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(t2-t1);
return ok(bytes).as(response.getHeader("Content-type"));
```

Average Time after 100+ request - 46873

```
ChannelBufferInputStream responseStream = (ChannelBufferInputStream) response.getBodyAsStream();
long t1 = System.nanoTime();

ArrayList<Byte> arrayList = new ArrayList<Byte>();
try {
    while (responseStream.available() > 0) {
        arrayList.add(responseStream.readByte());
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return internalServerError();
}
Iterator<Byte> iterator = arrayList.iterator();
byte[] bytes = new byte[arrayList.size()];
int i = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    bytes[i++] = iterator.next();
}

long t2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(t2-t1);
return ok(bytes).as(response.getHeader("Content-type"));
```

Average Time after 100+ request - 522848

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
byte[] bytes;
try {
    bytes = org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(responseStream);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return internalServerError();
}

long t2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(t2-t1);
```

Average Time after 100+ request - 45088

```
long t1 = System.nanoTime();
byte[] bytes;
try {
    bytes = sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(responseStream, -1, true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return internalServerError();
}

long t2 = System.nanoTime();
System.out.println(t2 - t1);
```

Average Time after 100+ request - 20180

Comment: Hey Matt, I've read through that post. I'm looking for max efficiency.

Comment: If you're that concerned about it, you should be measuring and comparing different implementations yourself. However, since you said "it seems to be running pretty fast" this does not _sound_ like a bottleneck, if you're trying to make your code run faster.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649100/cast-wrapper-array-to-corresponding-primitive-array

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida not really relevant here.

Comment: @MattBall The code hasn't been deployed to production yet, but since this code is called on every page load I want it to run as fast as possible to keep page load time down.

Comment: sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully() doesn't accept -1 as length any more, as of AdoptOpenJDK 8u242 at least.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. Use a `ByteArrayOutputStream` rather than an ArrayList. Then read chunks of bytes from the InputStream (without using `available()`, which should almost always never used) and write these chunks to the ByteArrayOutputStream, until the `read()` method returns -1. Then call toByteArray() on your `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

You could use Guava's [`ByteStreams.toByteArray()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html#toByteArray-java.io.InputStream-) method, which does all that for you, or you could read its source code to have a better idea of how it does it. Reading the [IO tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/bytestreams.html) might also help.

Comment: Thanks, let me test this out. I'll do some benchmark testing too

Comment: `available()` returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking. It could always return 0 (and does that by default).

Comment: Seeing some speed improvements, thanks

Comment: Any idea why `sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully` would be running twice as fast as all the other methods?

Comment: ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray() creates a new copy of the data, which is unnecessary. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 5):

What's wrong with [Apache Commons IO IOUtils.toByteArray](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) method? That's been optimized over many years for this purpose.

Comment: Hey, I didn't want to import a library for just one function.

Comment: Well, chances are you'll use more functions in that library over time, and what's the harm? Anyway, it's open source. Read the source and see how they do it if you don't want the whole thing.

Comment: What about using `sun.misc.IOUtils`? It's built into Java, but I've heard not to trust sun's libraries. `IOUtils.readFully(responseStream, -1, true);` This is giving me faster results though. Maybe I'll give in and use apache commons...

Comment: I've updated my benchmark test. Looks like sun.misc.IOUtils is performing fastest on my machine, but as I said before I've heard that sun's libraries aren't trustworthy.

Comment: That's just an old copy of the Apache one, AFAIK. And it won't be there necessarily if you ever run on the IBM JVM.

Comment: This is pretty weird. I did a more thorough benchmark test and `sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully` is running twice as fast as all the other methods.

Comment: I don't think one wants to import a whole library for one function. In my case it would have been a huge effort to do this (server restarts and stuff).

Comment: @sissonb Could you back up your claim that Suns libraries are 'not to be trusted' with a reason, reference or citation?  You may be right, but without evidence it's a rather unhelpful statement.

Comment: This is the warning about the library. `warning: IOUtils is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release`

Answer (score 1):

Why? This code is entirely equivalent to `read(byte[])` except that it does two extra copy steps on the entire data. You don't need any of this. A simple `read(byte[])` would be several times as fast.

The use of `available()` is invalid as well. You need the entire response, not just the part that can be read without blocking. You need to loop.

Comment: Thanks, I'm making these fixes now. I'll show the diff in a few minutes.

Comment: A simple read() doesn't guarantee (unless this ChannelBufferInputStream implementation brings this guarantee) that the whole stream is read. Maybe that's not what you really meant, but you need a reading loop until -1 is returned.

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed, clarified.