# Convert ArrayList<Byte> into a byte[]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, primitive-types

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array)

How to convert an `ArrayList<Byte>` into a `byte[]`?

`ArrayList.toArray()` gives me back a `Byte[]`.

Comment: ArrayList<Byte> is about the most inefficient way to store Bytes there is.  If you don't know how many bytes to will have using ByteArrayOutputStream with write() and toByteArray(), don't use List<Byte> if you can avoid it at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After calling toArray() you can pass the result into the Apache Commons toPrimitive method:

> https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive-java.lang.Byte:A->

Comment: For this you would still have to use `toArray()` in the list beforehand.

Comment: This method takes an array as parameter. Not an ``ArrayList``. It would require conversion from the ``ArrayList`` to an array, and then converting the ``Byte`` array to ``byte`` array. Not sure it would be the most efficient way to do the conversion.

Comment: @Vivien  I agree it may not be the most efficient, but probably the simplest to write.  If performance is a concern, I would use Michael's or Vivien's answer.

Comment: byte[] b_arr= ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(arrayList.toArray(new Byte[0]));

Comment: this solution doesn't work. toPrimitiveArray returns array of int

Comment: Read the last comment @coolcool1994

Comment: link is broken :(

Comment: @Andrew I fixed the link for you.

Comment: @JustinKSU, thank you so much. I think this edition will be useful for all users, not only for me :)

Answer (score 18):

```
byte[] result = new byte[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    result[i] = list.get(i).byteValue();
}
```

Yeah, Java's collections are annoying when it comes to primitive types.

Comment: missing brackets in size ()

Answer (score 8):

No built-in method comes to mind. However, coding one up is pretty straightforward:

```
public static byte[] toByteArray(List<Byte> in) {
    final int n = in.size();
    byte ret[] = new byte[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        ret[i] = in.get(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Note that this will give you a `NullPointerException` if `in` is `null` or if it contains `nulls`. It's pretty obvious how to change this function if you need different behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

```
byte[] data = new byte[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = (byte) list.get(i);
}
```

Please note that this can take some time due to the fact that `Byte` objects needs to be converted to `byte` values.

Also, if your list contains `null` values, this will throw a `NullPointerExcpetion`.