# Using lambda expression of Java 8, convert List<Byte> to primitive byte[], without external libraries

Tags: java, arrays, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Please Read first! My question is in **Java 8**,

Clearly, in time of these questions, java 8 did not exist yet.

[How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/718554/1410223) for today 10 years!
[Convert ArrayList<Byte> into a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6860055/1410223) for today 8 years!

I have this code:

```
List<Byte> listByte = new ArrayList<>();

// fill the List with Byte Wrapper...
```

Those result in errors:

```
// 1. option
byte[] arrayByte = listByte.stream().map(B -> B.byteValue()).toArray();

// 2. option
byte[] arrayByte = listByte.toArray(new byte[0]);
```

Is there another method instead for loop method?

Comment: Re: The other threads being "too old". The one about `int[]` has answers with Java 8 solutions. For `byte[]` there is nothing new in Java 8, primitive streams have not been added to all types on purpose, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/32459683/14955  Either way, the linked answers still work.

Comment: @Thilo You found the answer in the other questions?

Comment: @ChepeQuestn All answers on https://stackoverflow.com/q/6860055/14955 work here

Comment: The user's question says: Is there another method instead for loop method?

Comment: The for loop is the best method. But the accepted answer does not use a for loop. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6860106/14955

Comment: @ChepeQuestn The [answer by Tagir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32470838/1746118) in the other linked question does provide an approach(`toByteArray`) which is coupled with the requirement of using lambda here. Apart from which the normal for loop can also be written using lambda as `byte[] arrayBytes = new byte[listByte.size()];
        IntStream.range(0, listByte.size()).forEach(i -> arrayBytes[i] = listByte.get(i));`, if that qualifies as an answer to the question.

Comment: That same answer is also given right here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58360450/14955). But I would a) question the "requirement" of using lambda and b) take a hint from lack of ByteStreams and try to avoid having a `List<Byte>` in the first place. Practically all byte-manipulating libraries work with `byte[]` or `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try  doing like this:

```
listByte.stream().collect(ByteArrayOutputStream::new, (baos, i) -> baos.write((byte) i),
        (baos1, baos2) -> baos1.write(baos2.toByteArray(), 0, baos2.size()))
        .toByteArray()
```

Comment: The combiner is only used in parallel streams, and it is kind of hard to reason about how that would work in this case. Better use a version of collect that does not support combinations.

Comment: Yeah, I agree this is not the easiest thing to deal with, thanks