# how to convert ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> to int[][]?

Tags: java

I have an old function I can't change who want an int[][] for parameter is there a way to map 
`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>` to `int[][]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get the size of the ArrayLists into i and j ,respectively
Increment i and j according to your logic

```
int i = 0;
for(ArrayList<Integer> a1 : outer){
    int j=0;
    for(Integer k : a1){
       yourarray[i][j++] = k;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: any reason for the down vote ? if i am wrong at-least ,provide a reason , so that i can learn.

Comment: Hi sorry, you are never resetting "j". This will yield to fancy Index Out of Bounds exceptions. And in Java you should write variable names lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Maurice.

To convert `List<Integer>` to `int[]`, there's a [nice answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array/718558#718558) that you may find usefull.

Also note that Apache Commons has a [ArrayUtils class](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html), which has a method [`toPrimitive()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Integer%5B%5D%29) that does exactly this for one array level.

Edit (see comments below):

[msandiford](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183397/msandiford) also mentions the existence of [`guava`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/overview-summary.html) [`Ints`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html) class that provides a static [`int[] toArray(Collection<Integer> collection)`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29) method.

Comment: Added Apache Commons ArrayUtils class for completeness

Comment: Google guava has com.google.common.primitives.Ints which has a `toArray(Collection<Integer>)` method that's probably more efficient than `toPrimitive(foo.toArray())`. http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will need two levels of loops to do that.

Comment: there is not default util method?

Comment: no: toArray cannot be used because invoking it on one of the inner lists will give an Integer[] which is different from an int[].