# Convert ArrayList of Integer Objects to an int array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array)

I tried the code below, but it does not work. Do I have to make a loop copy the `ArrayList` into an array ?

```
int[]intArray = (int[]) integerArrayList.toArray();
```

Comment: Using streams:
`nums.stream().mapToInt(x -> x).toArray();`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If you want *primitive* type array, you can use [`Apache Commons`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)  [`ArrayUtils#toPrimitive`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Short%5b%5d%29) method to get primitive array from wrapper array: -

```
public static int[] toPrimitive(Integer[] array)
```

You can use it like this: -

```
int[] arr = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive((Integer[])integerArrayList.toArray());
```

Or, you can use the *1-arg* version of *toArray* method, that takes an *array* and returns the array of that type only. That way, you won't have to the *typecasting*.

```
List<Integer> myList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Integer[] wrapperArr = myList.toArray(new Integer[myList.size()]);

// If you want a `primitive` type array
int[] arr = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(wrapperArr);
```

---

However, if you are Ok with the `wrapper type` array *(Which certainly will not trouble you)*, then you *don't need* to do that last step.

---

Also, you can also create a *primitive* array, without having to create that intermediate *Wrapper type* array. For that you would have to write it through `loop`: -

```
int[] arr = new int[myList.size()];

for(int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    if (myList.get(i) != null) {
        arr[i] = myList.get(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `It does the same`. Loop over array and create new primitive array. And also adding another library for such a simple functionality does not make sense.

Comment: @AmitD. At least saves us from writing that loop, to get the work done.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to iterate through and copy it.

```
int[] intArray = new int[integerArrayList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
    intArray[i] = integerArrayList.get(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the loop, and you don't need typecast to `int`. Just change the declaration of `int` to `Integer`. Other code will use auto unboxing to `int` elements if required.

Look at [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

> ```
> // List adapter for primitive int array
> public static List<Integer> asList(final int[] a) {
>     return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
>         public Integer get(int i) { return a[i]; }
>         // Throws NullPointerException if val == null
>         public Integer set(int i, Integer val) {
>             Integer oldVal = a[i];
>             a[i] = val;
>             return oldVal;
>         }
>         public int size() { return a.length; }
>     };
> ```
>
> }

Answer (score 1):

you should be using arraylist's `toArray(T[] arr)` method instead of arrayList's `toArray()` with no args.
refer to that method signature [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29).

do it like below:

```
   ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
        al.add(2);
        al.add(3);
        Integer[] arr = al.toArray(new Integer[al.size()]);
        System.out.println(arr.length);//returns 2
```

Comment: This is incorrect as he is looking to create a primitive int array, not another array of Integer.