# Convert an arraylist to array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an Arraylist that I want to convert it into an array. I am using this:

```
double[] array = new double[list.size()];
double [] array = list.toArray(new double[list.size()]);
```

but, it does not work. Any idea how I can fix it? Thanks in advance. 
It seems it returns object.

Comment: So where is your list? Did you know that collection can contain only wrappers for primitives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For converting a `List<Double>` to a `double[]`, or anything where you need the primitive type, there's no alternative to doing a traditional `for` loop (or calling a third-party library method that does a traditional `for` loop, such as Guava's [`Doubles.toArray`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Doubles.html#toArray%28java.util.Collection%29)).

```
double[] array = new double[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  array[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

Alternately, you could do

```
Double[] array = list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);
```

which would get you the array of boxed `Double`s, which might suffice for your purposes anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A List can't contain primitive types. Assuming it contains instances of `Double`, the only way is to iterate over the list and unbox each element (hoping there's no null in the list):

```
double[] array = new double[list.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Double d : list) {
    array[i] = d;
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
Double[] array = new Double[list.size()];
list.toArray(array); // fill the array
```

and if you want an array of primitives, iterate over each element in the array:

```
double[] array = new double[list.size()];
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) array[i] = list.get(i).doubleValue();
```

Comment: Have you tried this?  The way generics work doesn't work like this.

Comment: @LouisWasserman You are right, I missed that :) .. updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the java docs:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Object Double not the primitive double:

```
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
...add data
Double[] array=list.toArray(new Double[list.size()]);
```

Comment: I doubt that is what the goal of the asker is.. They probably want to perform operations on those `doubles` as primitives.

Answer (score -1):

```
       StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(Object o:list){
            strBuffer.append(o);
        }
        double []x = new double[]{strBuffer.toString()};
```

I consider this should work

Comment: This answer does not work. This is the same as your [other answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16336520/922184). Please make sure your answers actually work before you post them.