# How do I convert an ArrayList to an Array then return it in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to create a method that creates a list of prime factors of a given number, then returns them in an array. Everything seems to be working fine except for the conversion of the ArrayList to an Array. Also, I'm not sure if I'm returning the array correctly.

Here's my code...

```
static int[] listOfPrimes(int num) {
    ArrayList primeList = new ArrayList();
    int count = 2;
    int factNum = 0;

    // Lists all primes factors.
    while(count*count<num) {
        if(num%count==0) {
            num /= count;
            primeList.add(count);
            factNum++;
        } else {
            if(count==2) count++;
            else count += 2;
    }
}
int[] primeArray = new int[primeList.size()];
primeList.toArray(primeArray);
return primeArray;
```

It returns this error message when I compile...

```
D:\JAVA>javac DivisorNumber.java
DivisorNumber.java:29: error: no suitable method found for toArray(int[])
            primeList.toArray(primeArray);
                     ^
method ArrayList.toArray(Object[]) is not applicable
  (actual argument int[] cannot be converted to Object[] by method invocatio
n conversion)
method ArrayList.toArray() is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
Note: DivisorNumber.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
1 error
```

Additionally, I'm not sure how to receive the returned array, so I need some help on that as well. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array)

Comment: Java Collections can only hold objects. int is a primitive data type and cannot be held in an ArrayList for example. You need to use Integer instead. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/960431/how-to-convert-listinteger-to-int-in-java

Comment: Do you use an IDE, like Netbeans, IntelliJ or Eclipse?

Comment: I do not like overcomplicated examples. Can you prove that you cannot demonstrate what you want to do in one line? Why the cycle is important?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for posting a duplicate post. It was 2:00 am, and I was tired of trying to find relevant posts. And sorry Val. Again, it was 2:00 am.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use the generified `toArray()` method, you'll need to use the `Integer` wrapper class instead of the primitive type `int`.

```
Integer[] primeArray = new Integer[primeList.size()];
primeList.toArray(primeArray);
```

The error the compiler is giving is stating that the method you want to call ([`List#toArray(T[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray(T[]))) doesn't apply to an argument of type `int[]`, just because an `int` is not an `Object` (it is a primitive type). An `Integer` *is* an `Object` however, wrapping an `int` (and this is one of the main reasons the `Integer` class exists).

Of course you could also iterate through the `List` manually and add the `Integer` elements in it as `int`s in an array.

There's a related question here on SO: [How to convert List to int[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/960431/851811) with lots of other suggestions (Apache commons, guava, ...)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was completely unaware that there was a difference between int and Integer.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Glad that helped. Remember to upvote helpful answers and accept the one you think better answered your question (see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/169503)). It will help other people visiting this question in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] primeArray = primeList.toArray(new int[primeList.size()]);
```

but I'm not really confident to be able to do this with `int` than with `Integer`

Answer (score -2):

change int[] array to Integer[]

```
static Integer[] listOfPrimes(int num) {
    List<Integer> primeList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int count = 2;
    int factNum = 0;

    // Lists all primes factors.
    while (count * count < num) {
        if (num % count == 0) {
            num /= count;
            primeList.add(count);
            factNum++;
        } else {
            if (count == 2)
                count++;
            else
                count += 2;
        }
    }

    return primeList.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}
```