# Making a variable length array of ints

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I want to have a array of integers where the length is variable.  The obvious choice is to use ArrayList but can I do this for primitive types such as

```
ArrayList<int> myArray=new ArrayList<int>();
```

I dont want to use

```
ArrayList<Integer>
```

because the Integer class is clumsy in terms of coding.

EDIT:  From the answers below I think the solution is to write my own Integer class.

To answer the question below about "clumsy" let me give a specific, and I would of thought common use for integers namely using the last member of the array in any place you would want the integer.  If I just call the array "name" then to get the actual integer that can be operated on I need

```
name.get(name.size()-1).intValue();
```

To me this seems like an awfully unwieldy expression for a simple integer - particularly if it appears in an expression twice.  It also seems that (most of the) methods available for the Integer class are absolutely redundant.  Take two examples

```
static int compare(int a, int b)
```

Quite unbelievably, according to the documentation, this method returns a-b!!

```
static Integer valueOf(int a)
```

returns an Integer instance of the integer a.  Can someone give me a single example where

```
new Integer(a)
```

does not achieve exactly the same result?

Comment: length is variable as in? mutable?

Comment: What do you mean by clumsy?

Comment: As in the length is undetermined at run time and the length needs to change dynamically

Comment: Try to get the integer value out of the array to use in an expression to see my point - but stay on topic and answer the question

Comment: Using primitives is almost always more 'clumsy' than there object equivalents? I don't get why you would insist on trying to hammer a square block into a round whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible to use primitive types as generic type.

Answer (score 2):

#### Method 1: (not recommended)

You can do something like this, but this doubles the code and is not efficient:

```
int[] a;

//get size (from command line maybe ow whatever method you want)
```

You can set size 0 initially, and for ex. you are transferring values from `arraylist` so you will have to write:

```
 while(itr.hasNext()){
  size++;} //itr is an object of Iterator
 int i=0;
 a=new int[size];
 // then loop again to store values
 while(itr.hasNext()){
  a[i]=itr.next();
  i++;}
```

#### Method 2:

Or you may use `ArrayList` without making it **clumsy** as follows:

ArrayList al=new ArrayList();

then you may declare Integer objects as `volatile` and perform operations on them just as you do with the primitive types.

#### Method 3: (not recommended)

Or simply write:

```
ArrayList al=new ArrayList();//ignore the warning about <E>
int x=2;
al.add(2);
```

#### Method 4: (recommended)

If I were you I would use `ArrayList<Integer>`.

UPDATE: Another thing that might work is that you may initially create an `ArrayList<Integer>` and store values there and later convert it to `int[]`

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array) SO answer tells about the conversion. Quoted the code form there:

```
public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers)
  {
     int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
      for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
      {
         ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
      }
     return ret;
   }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How does declaring the variable volatile help?

Answer (score 0):

Well I would recommend you do use ArrayList and avoid primitive types in this case.

You can't change the size of an array once created. You have to allocate it bigger than you think you'll ever need

or

Accept the overhead of having to reallocate it to a new larger array and copy the data from the old to the new:

```
System.arraycopy(oldItems, 0, newItems, 0, 10);
```

But Much simpler to go with ArrayList.