# I want to convert an ArrayList<Integer> that was put into the args bundle of a fragment to type Integer[] for an other method?

Tags: java, android, for-loop, android-fragments, arraylist

I want to convert an  `ArrayList<Integer>` that was put into the `args` bundle of a fragment to type `Integer[]` so I can pass it to a method that requires the type `Integer[]`. I have

```
ArrayList<Integer> friends
```

I then created an empty `Integer` Array.

```
Integer[] bal= new Integer[friends.size()];
```

I know I have to do something with the `for` loop!!

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array

Answer (score 2):

In order to fill the array with the values from your array list you can use a loop (like the 'for loop' you mentioned) to iterate through the ArrayList and place its data into the array.

You can use the following code to accomplish this:

```java
Integer[] bal = new Integer[friends.size()];
for(int i=0; i < friends.size(); i++){
  bal[i] = friends.get(i);
}
```

Let me know if this is all you need, or if you have any other issues!

EDIT: As mentioned in another answer below, you don't have to create a new array and manually fill it with the values from the ArrayList. You could use the `toArray()` method on the ArrayList class to convert the ArrayList into an array as follows: `Integer[] bal = friends.toArray(new Integer[friends.size()]);`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply convert *ArrayList to Array* you can do it as :-

`Integer[] bal = friends.toArray(new Integer[friends.size()]);`