# array with zero values

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

If the import integers are `5 2 1 12 2 10 4 13 5`

However, the output shows with many "0" if the arraysize is large(20 now).

Result:

[image]

Therefore, I may ask which parts go wrong and any solution to fix the null parts.

Comment: What is your `mergeSort()` method?

Comment: edited. it's Sort()

Comment: you are missing an import of 'ArrayList', just for the sake of it...

Comment: don't name your methods with a capital letter.

Comment: You are initializing array1, so the remaining unfilled values will be default by zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the zeros are your problem, than don't initialize your array with a constant value ("20", in your example).

Just change your scanning code to:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("C:/text.txt"));
ArrayList<Integer> array1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(scanner.hasNextInt() ){
    array1.add(scanner.nextInt());
}
```

Also, you will need to convert your ArratList to an int array. The following code will help (copied from : [How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/718554/how-to-convert-an-arraylist-containing-integers-to-primitive-int-array)):

```
public static int[] convertArrayListToIntArray(List<Integer> integers)
{
    int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
    Iterator<Integer> iterator = integers.iterator();
    for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    {
        ret[i] = iterator.next().intValue();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: @krstore - see the link added. Because my answer requires you to change your data-structure from a primitive int array to an array list, and I don't want you needing to change all of your other methods (int[]->ArrayList<Integer>) - I added a conversion method.

Comment: @krstore I changed the method's name. Better now?

Comment: cannot find symbol - class iterator ?

Comment: oh I see, I finally get it right. thank you for your passionate

Comment: @krstore Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

By doing this in your code:

```
int [] array1 = new int [20];
```

You are saying, initialize array1 with 0 as a default value for all.

Now if you enter only 10 values, rest of the 10 values will be zero.. hence when sorted.. 0 is less than 1 it appears first..

clear?