# ArrayList<double[] > Add two existing arrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am working on a lab where I have to add two existing arrayLists to ArrayList double[] object.

```
// first two arrayLists
ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList <>();
ArrayList<Double> list2 = new ArrayList <>();

// masterList - need to add list and list2.
ArrayList<double[]> masterList = new ArrayList<>();
```

I then need to pass the masterList to a collection:

```
Collection<double[]> c = masterList;
```

Edit: How I've tried to add the lists to the masterList

```
            masterList.add(list);
            masterList.add(list2);

            error: The method add(double[]) in the type ArrayList<double[]> 
            is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Double>)

            masterList[0] = list;
            masterList[1] = list2;

            error: The type of the expression must be an array type but it 
            resolved to ArrayList<double[]>
```

I'm having trouble adding list and list2 to MasterList. I can't seem to use add or addAll methods.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need a list of arrays?

Comment: "I can't seem to use `add` or `addAll` methods." -- wanna post what you tried, so we can figure out where you went wrong, instead of guessing what you were doing wrong?

Comment: @AndyTurner I need to use the Collection<double[]> c = masterList; in a pvalue calculation that requires a Collection of two arrays.

Comment: Then your question is really how to convert `ArrayList<Double>` into `double[]`, right? Because once you've done that twice, creating the `ArrayList<double[]>` from those two `double[]` should be easy enough, right? So when you searched the web for how to convert a list of boxed values to an array of primitives, you didn't find anything?

Comment: @AJNeufeld added what I've tried.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/718558/3690024)

Comment: Maybe what he wanted was not what you are suggesting but:
`Collection<Double[]> c = masterList;`
`masterList.add((Double[]) list.toArray());`

Comment: @Andreas this is not correct. We have guide lines from our professor that say specifically we need to add two ArrayLists to a single ArrayList<Double[]>.

Comment: `ArrayList<Double[]>` is not `ArrayList<double[]>`!

Comment: @ErnestoUlloa thanks for the reply. Tried your suggestion with the same errors I posed in my edit.

Comment: @Blurr.P this should be the result:
    `ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList <>();
    ArrayList<Double> list2 = new ArrayList <>();
    ArrayList<Double[]> masterList = new ArrayList<>();
    Collection<Double[]> c = masterList;
    masterList.add((Double[]) list.toArray());
    masterList.add((Double[]) list2.toArray());`

Sorry i cant format the code properly here

Comment: @ErnestoUlloa that does fix my issue of adding the two lists. But I need to use a method to calculate pValue which takes a collection of doubles. When I attempt to pass collection c to that method I get this error: 

The method anovaPValue(Collection<double[]>) in the type OneWayAnova is not applicable for the arguments (Collection<Double[]>)

Comment: @Blurr.P for that you will need to follow their explanation, the result would be something like this:
`ArrayList<double[]> masterList = new ArrayList<>();
        masterList.add(new double[list.size()]);
        masterList.add(new double[list2.size()]);
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            masterList.get(0)[i]= list.get(i);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
            masterList.get(1)[i]= list2.get(i);
        }
        Collection<double[]> topass = masterList;`

Comment: @ErnestoUlloa Thank you very much for your help. I'll give this a try. Really appreciate it.

Comment: And that code is what to duplicate link is about, i.e. converting a `List` of boxed values (`Integer` / `Double`) to an *array* of primitive values (`int` / `double`). What dup. link doesn't cover is adding those two arrays to a `List<double[]>`, but that is such a simple thing you shouldn't need an explicit answer to figure that out.