# Convert Map <Integer, Long> to array of Integer

Tags: collections, java-8

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? `p.getVote()`, and the collection counting logic return a Long, but I am trying to make my end output an array of ints.

```
Map<Integer, Long> counters = iqr.getQgagueUniqueVotes().stream()
                               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p -> ((int)p.getVote()), 
                                    Collectors.counting()));
Collection<Long> values = counters.values();
long[] targetArray = values.toArray(new Long[values.size()]);
```

Error:

```
Incompatible type: Inference variable has incompatible upper bound
```

Comment: Is your issue just with converting `Map<Integer, Long>` to `long[]`? Then you probably should replace the initialisation based on a stream statement (that's also dependent on a variable you didn't show) with some hard-coded data. See also: [mcve].

Comment: Similar: [How to convert an ArrayList containing Integers to primitive int array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/718554)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the type of the `targetArray` array to a type `Long`:

```
Long[] targetArray = values.toArray(new Long[values.size()]);
```

or create a stream of the values and map to a type `long` then collect to an array.

```
long[] targetArray = values.stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).toArray();
```

Comment: I recommend [this article](https://shipilev.net/blog/2016/arrays-wisdom-ancients/) regarding the pattern of using `.toArray(new Long[values.size()])` instead of `.toArray(new Long[0])`.