# How can I convert List<Integer> to int[] in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

How can I convert a `List<Integer>` to `int[]` in Java?

I'm confused because `List.toArray()` actually returns an `Object[]`, which can be cast to neither `Integer[]` nor `int[]`.

Right now I'm using a loop to do so:

```
int[] toIntArray(List<Integer> list) {
  int[] ret = new int[list.size()];
  for(int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++)
    ret[i] = list.get(i);
  return ret;
}
```

Is there's a better way to do this?

<sub>This is similar to the question
*[How can I convert int[] to Integer[] in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880581/java-convert-int-to-integer)*.</sub>

Comment: You can only cast to Integer[] by using: `Integer[] arr = (Integer[])list.toArray(new Integer[list.size]);`

Comment: @ripper234, eddie's solution is worse than the one on the question. actually the original one is technically the best as long as the List is RandomAccess impl (even it will be properly unrolled and the bounds check for array removed)

Comment: @Hardcoded you might want to edit your comment to use list.size() method and drop the unnecessary cast.

Comment: @sactiw How should I do this? This comment is written 3 years ago and you can only edit your comments for the first 5 minutes.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this now in Java 8?

Comment: (@Makoto : see [Pshemo's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23945015/3789665))

Comment: int[] arr = listOfIntegers.stream().mapToInt(x->x).toArray();

Answer (score 263, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't believe there really *is* a better way of doing this due to the nature of Java's handling of primitive types, boxing, arrays and generics. In particular:

- `List<T>.toArray` won't work because there's no conversion from `Integer` to `int`
- You can't use `int` as a type argument for generics, so it would *have* to be an `int`-specific method (or one which used reflection to do nasty trickery).

I believe there are libraries which have autogenerated versions of this kind of method for all the primitive types (i.e. there's a template which is copied for each type). It's ugly, but that's the way it is I'm afraid :(

Even though the [`Arrays`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) class came out before generics arrived in Java, it would still have to include all the horrible overloads if it were introduced today (assuming you want to use primitive arrays).

Comment: Also see ColinD's answer about guava's Ints.toArray(Collection<Integer>)

Comment: @JonSkeet you mean like the horrible overloads that exists already in the Arrays class for `binarySearch`, `copyOf`, `copyOfRange`...? I wonder why they couldn't add another set of horrible overloads.

Comment: @ron ColinD's answer doesn't give anything but what the OP already had - for loop to fill primitive array with non-primitive one.

Comment: meanwhile at Oracle java engineers are fixated with overcomplicating the language with modules...

Comment: @bvdb: I'm saying that without other libraries (which basically still have the loop, but in their code not yours), I don't believe there's a better approach. That's a significantly stronger assertion than saying I don't know whether or not there is a better approach.

Answer (score 1057):

With streams added in Java 8 we can write code like:

```
int[] example1 = list.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
// OR
int[] example2 = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

---

Thought process:

- The simple `Stream#toArray` returns an `Object[]` array, so it is not what we want. Also, `Stream#toArray(IntFunction<A[]> generator)` which returns `A[]` doesn't do what we want, because the generic type `A` can't represent the primitive type `int`
- So it would be nice to have some kind of stream which would be designed to handle primitive type `int` instead of the reference type like `Integer`, because its `toArray` method will most likely also return an `int[]` array (returning something else like `Object[]` or even boxed `Integer[]` would be unnatural for `int`). And fortunately Java 8 has such a stream which is [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)
- So now the only thing we need to figure out is how to convert our `Stream<Integer>` (which will be returned from `list.stream()`) to that shiny `IntStream`.

  Quick searching in documentation of `Stream` while looking for methods which return `IntStream` points us to our solution which is [`mapToInt(ToIntFunction<? super T> mapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) method. All we need to do is provide a mapping from `Integer` to `int`.

  Since [`ToIntFunction`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/ToIntFunction.html) is *functional interface* we can also provide its instance via *lambda* or *method reference*.

  Anyway to convert Integer to int we can use [`Integer#intValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#intValue--) so inside `mapToInt` we can write:

  ```
  mapToInt( (Integer i) -> i.intValue() )
  ```

  (or some may prefer: `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)`.)

  But similar code can be generated using unboxing, since the compiler knows that the result of this lambda must be of type `int` (the lambda used in `mapToInt` is an implementation of the `ToIntFunction` interface which expects as body a method of type: `int applyAsInt(T value)` which is expected to return an `int`).

  So we can simply write:

  ```
  mapToInt((Integer i)->i)
  ```

  Also, since the `Integer` type in `(Integer i)` can be inferred by the compiler because `List<Integer>#stream()` returns a `Stream<Integer>`, we can also skip it which leaves us with

  ```
  mapToInt(i -> i)
  ```

Comment: Clearly the best solution. Too bad it lacks explanation.

Comment: @PimpTrizkit Updated this answer a little. Hope it is clearer now.

Comment: @Pshemo - Thanks! I didn't personally need an explanation. But I hate seeing the perfect answer without one!  Regardless, your explanation did educate me and was helpful. I wonder why the `mapTo...` functions don't allow for `null` lambda.... like sort does.... which makes it default to a default behavior... in this case,  `i -> i` would be a perfect default behavior.

Comment: I guess this answer is faster than ColinD's answer using Guava, right?

Comment: @vefthym I didn't test it, but I suspect that both solution work on same simple principle so I would expect similar speed (but feel free to benchmark it). One advantage of this answer is that it doesn't require additional libraries as long as we have Java 8.

Comment: thanks to this, I learned about streams of primitive types. Great solution and explanation, thank you.

Comment: Hands down the best solution!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work with `byte`, `short`, `char`, or `float` arrays...

Comment: @SolomonUcko True, there are no `Stream`s corresponding to those primitive types, so also there are no methods in Stream class like `mapToByte(...)`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my opinion. Also, could you please update the answer to use method reference (if you feel so)?

Comment: Here's the equivalent for a byte array, borrowing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683#answer-32470838) (and its comments): `byte[] array = list.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(i -> i).collect(ByteArrayOutputStream::new, (b, i) -> b.write((byte) i), (b1, b2) -> { try { b2.writeTo(b1); } catch(IOException e) { } }).toByteArray();`

Comment: This exactly why people prefer Python to Java.

Answer (score 222):

In addition to Commons Lang, you can do this with [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s method [`Ints.toArray(Collection<Integer> collection)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray(java.util.Collection)):

```
List<Integer> list = ...
int[] ints = Ints.toArray(list);
```

This saves you having to do the intermediate array conversion that the Commons Lang equivalent requires yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, the intermediate array is hidden inside Guava:
`Object[] boxedArray = collection.toArray();`

Comment: "Fortunately, the intermediate array is hidden inside Guava." - Fixed that for you. ;)

Answer (score 182):

The easiest way to do this is to make use of [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang).  It has a handy ArrayUtils class that can do what you want.  Use the [`toPrimitive`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28java.lang.Integer%5b%5d%29) method with the overload for an array of `Integer`s.

```
List<Integer> myList;
 ... assign and fill the list
int[] intArray = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(myList.toArray(new Integer[myList.size()]));
```

This way you don't reinvent the wheel.  Commons Lang has a great many useful things that Java left out.  Above, I chose to create an Integer list of the right size.  You can also use a 0-length static Integer array and let Java allocate an array of the right size:

```
static final Integer[] NO_INTS = new Integer[0];
   ....
int[] intArray2 = ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(myList.toArray(NO_INTS));
```

Comment: The `toPrimitive` link is broken.

Comment: Here's a link to 2.6 Commons Lang API: [toPrimitive](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive(java.lang.Integer[]))

Comment: Note that this will entail 2 allocations and copies: `myList.toArray()` will create an `Integer[]` and populate it, while `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive()` will allocate an `int[]` and unbox the input.

Answer (score 85):

**Java 8** has given us an easy way to do this via streams...

Using the collections `stream()` function and then mapping to ints, you'll get an IntStream. With the `IntStream` we can call toArray() which gives us `int []`

```
int [] ints = list.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

[to int []](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html)

[to IntStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633913/how-do-i-get-an-intstream-from-a-listinteger)

Answer (score 62):

Use:

```
int[] toIntArray(List<Integer> list)  {
    int[] ret = new int[list.size()];
    int i = 0;
    for (Integer e : list)
        ret[i++] = e;
    return ret;
}
```

This slight change to your code is to avoid expensive list indexing (since a List is not necessarily an ArrayList, but it could be a linked list, for which random access is expensive).

Comment: I dont understand: looking up an elepment in an array is not slow.  It runs in O, where n is the size of the array, ie it's not dependent on the size of the array at all or anything.

In C:

myarray[c] is the same as:

myarray + c * sizeof( myarray[0] )

... which runs *very* fast.

Comment: The method takes List as argument, not all implementations have fast random access (like ArrayList)

Comment: @Hugh: The difference is not how the array is accessed, but how the List is accessed. `list.get(i)` performs bounds checks and stuff for each access. I don't know whether the new solution is actually better, but Mike says so at least, so perhaps it is.  

Edit: I forgot that Java allows indexing into a linked list (I'm used to C++'s std::list, which does not allow it). So what arjantop said about non-ArrayList is true as well; indexing isn't necessarily fast even without the bounds checks.

Comment: @Lajnold The bounds checks for an `ArrayList` are free in a modern JIT. However, I'd prefer if Java more followed STL and implemented only methods which really make sense (`LinkedList::get(int)` does not as it may be arbitrary slow).

Comment: @maaartinus The entire purpose of interfaces is to separate implementation from interface. It makes perfect sense the way it is solved in Java if you understand the underlying idea. [Here](https://www2.ccs.neu.edu/research/demeter/papers/context-journal/node16.html) is some information about it.

Comment: Is there a reason behind only allowing Lists instead of Iterables? Or is it just to fit the question? Thanks.

Answer (score 14):

Here is a **Java 8** single line code for this:

```
public int[] toIntArray(List<Integer> intList){
    return intList.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are simply mapping an `Integer` to an `int` then you should consider [using parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html), since your mapping logic does not rely on any variables outside its scope.

```
int[] arr = list.parallelStream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

Just be aware of this

> Note that parallelism is not automatically faster than performing operations serially, although it can be if you have enough data and processor cores. While aggregate operations enable you to more easily implement parallelism, it is still your responsibility to determine if your application is suitable for parallelism.

---

There are two ways to map Integers to their primitive form:

1. Via a `ToIntFunction`.

   ```
   mapToInt(Integer::intValue)
   ```
2. Via explicit [unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) with lambda expression.

   ```
   mapToInt(i -> i.intValue())
   ```
3. Via implicit (auto-) unboxing with lambda expression.

   ```
   mapToInt(i -> i)
   ```

---

Given a list with a `null` value

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(1, 2, null, 4, 5);
```

Here are three options to handle `null`:

1. Filter out the `null` values before mapping.

   ```
   int[] arr = list.parallelStream().filter(Objects::nonNull).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
   ```
2. Map the `null` values to a default value.

   ```
   int[] arr = list.parallelStream().map(i -> i == null ? -1 : i).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
   ```
3. Handle `null` inside the lambda expression.

   ```
   int[] arr = list.parallelStream().mapToInt(i -> i == null ? -1 : i.intValue()).toArray();
   ```

Comment: Note that `mapToInt(Integer::intValue)` and `mapToInt(i -> i.intValue())` are strictly identical (two ways of expressing the exact same method call), and all three are effectively identical (same bytecode).

Comment: This is awesome, thanks for sharing it.!

Answer (score 9):

This simple loop is always correct! no bugs

```
  int[] integers = new int[myList.size()];
  for (int i = 0; i < integers.length; i++) {
      integers[i] = myList.get(i);
  }
```

Comment: "Valid" is not the same as "ideal", and performance problems can be considered bugs. `List#get(int)` is not guaranteed to be a constant-time operation, as you may have assumed, so it shouldn't be used for iteration. Instead, use an iterator, which is designed for this use case. Either use the Java 5+ foreach loop or call `List#iterator()` and work with the iterator. Also, the list's size could change during this loop, leading to either an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or an incomplete array. Many iterator implementations have well-documented strategies to handle this situation.

Comment: Far better than the dog's dinner that is Java streams

Comment: This is ***identical*** to the one in the question. The question was *"Is there's a better way to do this?"*. How does this answer the question? Most of the other answers attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

I've noticed several uses of *for* loops, but you don't even need anything inside the loop. I mention this only because the original question was trying to find less verbose code.

```
int[] toArray(List<Integer> list) {
    int[] ret = new int[ list.size() ];
    int i = 0;
    for( Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator();
         it.hasNext();
         ret[i++] = it.next() );
    return ret;
}
```

If Java allowed multiple declarations in a *for* loop the way C++ does, we could go a step further and do for(int i = 0, Iterator it...

In the end though (this part is just my opinion), if you are going to have a helping function or method to do something for you, just set it up and forget about it. It can be a one-liner or ten; if you'll never look at it again you won't know the difference.

Answer (score 5):

There is really no way of "one-lining" what you are trying to do, because toArray returns an Object[] and you cannot cast from Object[] to int[] or Integer[] to int[].

Comment: You *can* cast between Object[] and Integer[] due to array covariance - but you can't cast between int[] and Integer[].

Comment: thanks for correcting me I will edit my answer to reflect what you said.

Answer (score 4):

```
int[] ret = new int[list.size()];       
Iterator<Integer> iter = list.iterator();
for (int i=0; iter.hasNext(); i++) {       
    ret[i] = iter.next();                
}                                        
return ret;
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. What is the idea/gist?

Answer (score 3):

Also try [Dollar](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/) ([check this revision](http://bitbucket.org/dfa/dollar/changeset/cea42757d873)):

```
import static com.humaorie.dollar.Dollar.*
...

List<Integer> source = ...;
int[] ints = $(source).convert().toIntArray();
```

Comment: Links in answer give *"404 | Repository not found"*.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use the `List<?>` skeletal implementation from the Java collections API. It appears to be quite helpful in this particular case:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Test {

    // Helper method to convert int arrays into Lists
    static List<Integer> intArrayAsList(final int[] a) {
        if(a == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        return new AbstractList<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public Integer get(int i) {
                return a[i]; // Autoboxing
            }
            @Override
            public Integer set(int i, Integer val) {
                final int old = a[i];
                a[i] = val; // Auto-unboxing
                return old; // Autoboxing
            }
            @Override
            public int size() {
                return a.length;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        int[] a = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        Collections.reverse(intArrayAsList(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
}
```

Beware of boxing/unboxing drawbacks.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question -- the OP asked how to convert from a List to an array.

Answer (score 2):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/), you can do the following if you have a list of type  `java.util.List<Integer>`:

```
List<Integer> integers = Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int[] ints = LazyIterate.adapt(integers).collectInt(i -> i).toArray();

Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ints);
```

If you already have an Eclipse Collections type like [`MutableList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/MutableList.html), you can do the following:

```
MutableList<Integer> integers = Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int[] ints = integers.asLazy().collectInt(i -> i).toArray();

Assert.assertArrayEquals(new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, ints);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 0):

Using a lambda you could do this (compiles in JDK lambda):

```
public static void main(String ars[]) {
    TransformService transformService = (inputs) -> {
        int[] ints = new int[inputs.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Integer element : inputs) {
            ints[ i++ ] = element;
        }
        return ints;
    };

    List<Integer> inputs = new ArrayList<Integer>(5) { {add(10); add(10);} };

    int[] results = transformService.transform(inputs);
}

public interface TransformService {
    int[] transform(List<Integer> inputs);
}
```

Comment: You could not have done that when the question was asked, but this is a good way to handle the situation now (assuming you have upgraded Java). What you have done could be further modified to provide a general way to transform lots of things with the same methodology. +1

Comment: The solution here is only in the loop code. The rest (functional interface, lambda, main method, list with dummy data) is extraneous and doesn't help answer the question.