# How to convert int[] into List<Integer> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, boxing, autoboxing

How do I convert `int[]` into `List<Integer>` in Java?

Of course, I'm interested in any other answer than doing it in a loop, item by item. But if there's no other answer, I'll pick that one as the best to show the fact that this functionality is not part of Java.

Comment: We can make use of IntStream.Of(array).collect(Collectors.toList)

Comment: @SarojKumarSahoo There is no one-argument `collect` in `IntStream`.

Comment: There is no `build-in` way to do it. You must do it manually, declare an ArrayList and add each value in the int Array to ArrayList. What a miss!

Answer (score 351, accepted):

There is no shortcut for converting from `int[]` to `List<Integer>` as `Arrays.asList` does not deal with boxing and will just create a `List<int[]>` which is not what you want. You have to make a utility method.

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(ints.length);
for (int i : ints)
{
    intList.add(i);
}
```

Comment: It is best to initialise the list with the size of the array

Comment: @David Rabinowitz - Not sure what to say to that :)

Comment: If you insist to use the ArrayList implementation, why not just use the overloaded constructor to do: new ArrayList(myArray) ?

Comment: I dont think there is such a constructor

Comment: for (int i : ints) intList.add(i);

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood - David means that this is better: new ArrayList<Integer>(ints.length);

Comment: @willcodejavaforfood: declaring the size of the ArrayList when it is being constructed will prevent it having to internally resize after a certain amount is added. Not sure if the benefit is small, but there's definitely a benefit.

Comment: @StephenDenne That is not possible since ints may be any array like {3, 40, 50}. In your case, there will be ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @Danny: Don't edit the meaning of another person's answer for no good reason. This one was old and accepted, it would have been better to leave a comment.

Comment: @Daemonthread not sure why you think there would be an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in Stephen Denne's for-loop.

Comment: The array list class empty constructor creates a list with size of ten in this case. The backend of the class is a Object[] with the size of ten elements. :)

Comment: `new ArrayList<Integer>() {{ for (int i : ints) add(i); }}`

Comment: @saka1029 For everyone thinking of using your solution, be aware that double brace initialisation comes with significant consequences. Use it wisely.

Comment: list.add(new int[]{1,2,3}); To create the list directly from the int array

Answer (score 576):

## Streams

1. In Java 8+ you can make a stream of your `int` array. Call either [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#stream(int%5B%5D)) or [`IntStream.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#of(int...)).
2. Call [`IntStream#boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed()) to use boxing conversion from `int` primitive to [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html) objects.
3. Collect into a list using `Stream.collect( Collectors.toList() )`. Or more simply in Java 16+, call [`Stream#toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toList()).

Example:

```
int[] ints = {1,2,3};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In Java 16 and later:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().toList();
```

Comment: Equivalent to: Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

Comment: @njfrost You're right and IntStream.of just calls Arrays.stream so I've improved the answer following your suggestion

Comment: For some reason this doesn't seem to be returning the expected result type on Android Studio(works on eclipse) It says, expected List<Integer>   found List<Object>.

Comment: It looks clean and concise but when I used this as opposed to the basic solution provided by @willcodejavaforfood on leetcode the program performance degraded in terms of  memory as well as runtime

Comment: @chitreshsirohi that is because lambda functions used inside streams result in Java to make some anonymous classes.

Comment: This solution is little complex to me. 
-------
I use bellow solution
-----------------------
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(ints.length);
for (int i : ints)
{
    intList.add(i);
}

If we talks about complexity, then which one is batter?

Comment: `IntStream.of(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Why does `Arrays.asList(arr)` evidently return a list of a single element, the `arr` array? I thought converting an array to an `ArrayList` is as simple as `new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(arr))`

Comment: I am getting code sonar issue i.e "Closeable Not Stored(Java)". Is there any way we can avoid this sonar issue?

Comment: The only issue here is that the resulting list is immutable as toList() is really this call return (List<T>) Collections.unmodifiableList(new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(this.toArray()))); This means you can only read this list and won't be able to change it in anyway.

Answer (score 194):

Also from [guava libraries](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html)... com.google.common.primitives.Ints:

```
List<Integer> Ints.asList(int...)
```

Comment: This one should be the right answer. See the second sentence of the question: "Of course, I'm interested in any other answer than doing it in a loop, item by item."

Comment: There are a few subtleties here. The returned list uses the provided array as backing store, so you should not mutate the array. The list also doesn't guarantee identity of the contained Integer objects. That is, the result of list.get(0) == list.get(0) is not specified.

Comment: Beware of the method reference count on Android when adding libraries. Good find though.

Comment: In Android I had to add `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-buildtools:2.9.0'` to build.gradle for this to work.

Answer (score 117):

Arrays.asList will not work as some of the other answers expect.

This code will **not** create a list of 10 integers. It will print **1**, not **10**:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
List lst = Arrays.asList(arr);
System.out.println(lst.size());
```

This will create a list of integers:

```
List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);
```

If you already have the array of ints, there is not quick way to convert, you're better off with the loop.

On the other hand, if your array has Objects, not primitives in it, Arrays.asList will work:

```
String str[] = { "Homer", "Marge", "Bart", "Lisa", "Maggie" };
List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(str);
```

Comment: Do note, that that list is immutable

Comment: Arrays.asList(arr) in the above comment will generate a list of type List<int[]> which is incompatible with List<Integer>.
If one were to try to assign the output to a variable like so
```
List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(arr);
```
you'd get the following error
    |  Error:
    |  incompatible types: inference variable T has incompatible bounds
    |      equality constraints: java.lang.Integer
    |      lower bounds: int[]
    |  List<Integer> l = Arrays.asList(a);
    |                    ^--------------^

Comment: this is wrong! it generates List<int[]>

Answer (score 56):

I'll add another answer with a different method; no loop but an anonymous class that will utilize the autoboxing features:

```
public List<Integer> asList(final int[] is)
{
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
            public Integer get(int i) { return is[i]; }
            public int size() { return is.length; }
    };
}
```

Comment: +1 this is shorter than mine but mine works for all primitives types

Comment: While quicker and using less memory than creating an ArrayList, the trade off is List.add() and List.remove() don't work.

Comment: I quite like this solution for large arrays with sparse access patterns but for frequently accessed elements it would result in many unnecessary instantiations of Integer (e.g. if you accessed the same element 100 times).  Also you would need to define Iterator and wrap the return value in Collections.unmodifiableList.

Comment: @Christoffer thanks. I have added the `set` method and now I can even sort the array...

Answer (score 46):

The smallest piece of code would be:

```
public List<Integer> myWork(int[] array) {
    return Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(array));
}
```

where ArrayUtils comes from commons-lang :)

Comment: Just note `ArrayUtils` it's a relative big library for an Android app

Comment: The opposite operation is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/960507/1333157 `ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(...)` is the key.

Answer (score 37):

In Java 8 with stream:

```
int[] ints = {1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Collections.addAll(list, Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new));
```

or with Collectors

```
List<Integer> list =  Arrays.stream(ints).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Why not simply use a collector?

Answer (score 24):

In Java 8 :

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3};
IntStream.of(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 23):

If you are using java 8, we can use the stream API to convert it into a list.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr)     // IntStream 
                                .boxed()        // Stream<Integer>
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also use the IntStream to convert as well.

```
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(arr) // return Intstream
                                    .boxed()        // Stream<Integer>
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

There are other external library like guava and apache commons 
 also available convert it.

cheers.

Answer (score 13):

It's also worth checking out [this bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4993464), which was closed with reason "Not a defect" and the following text:

"Autoboxing of entire arrays is not specified behavior, for good reason.
It can be prohibitively expensive for large arrays."

Answer (score 10):

```
int[] arr = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr)     // IntStream
                            .boxed()        // Stream<Integer>
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

see [this](https://www.techiedelight.com/convert-int-array-list-integer/)

Answer (score 8):

give a try to this class:

```
class PrimitiveWrapper<T> extends AbstractList<T> {

    private final T[] data;

    private PrimitiveWrapper(T[] data) {
        this.data = data; // you can clone this array for preventing aliasing
    }

    public static <T> List<T> ofIntegers(int... data) {
        return new PrimitiveWrapper(toBoxedArray(Integer.class, data));
    }

    public static <T> List<T> ofCharacters(char... data) {
        return new PrimitiveWrapper(toBoxedArray(Character.class, data));
    }

    public static <T> List<T> ofDoubles(double... data) {
        return new PrimitiveWrapper(toBoxedArray(Double.class, data));
    }  

    // ditto for byte, float, boolean, long

    private static <T> T[] toBoxedArray(Class<T> boxClass, Object components) {
        final int length = Array.getLength(components);
        Object res = Array.newInstance(boxClass, length);

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            Array.set(res, i, Array.get(components, i));
        }

        return (T[]) res;
    }

    @Override
    public T get(int index) {
        return data[index];
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return data.length;
    }
}
```

testcase:

```
List<Integer> ints = PrimitiveWrapper.ofIntegers(10, 20);
List<Double> doubles = PrimitiveWrapper.ofDoubles(10, 20);
// etc
```

Answer (score 6):

The best shot:

```java
    /**
     * Integer modifiable fixed length list of an int array or many int's.
     *
     * @author Daniel De Leon.
     */
    public class IntegerListWrap extends AbstractList<Integer> {
    
        int[] data;
    
        public IntegerListWrap(int... data) {
            this.data = data;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return data[index];
        }
    
        @Override
        public Integer set(int index, Integer element) {
            int r = data[index];
            data[index] = element;
            return r;
        }
    
        @Override
        public int size() {
            return data.length;
        }
    }
```

- Support get and set.
- No memory data duplication.
- No wasting time in loops.

Examples:

```
int[] intArray = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> integerListWrap = new IntegerListWrap(intArray);
List<Integer> integerListWrap1 = new IntegerListWrap(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: I like it the most. But I'd still use guava to have straight-forward solution :)

Answer (score 4):

What about this:

```java
int[] a = {1,2,3};
Integer[] b = ArrayUtils.toObject(a);
List<Integer> c = Arrays.asList(b);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another possibility, again with Java 8 Streams:

```
void intArrayToListOfIntegers(int[] arr, List<Integer> list) {
    IntStream.range(0, arr.length).forEach(i -> list.add(arr[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're open to using a third party library, this will work in [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> integers = IntLists.mutable.with(a).collect(i -> i);
Assert.assertEquals(Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3), integers);
```

Note: I am a committer for [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).

Answer (score 2):

```
   /* Integer[] to List<Integer> */



        Integer[] intArr = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
        List<Integer> arrList = new ArrayList<>();
        arrList.addAll(Arrays.asList(intArr));
        System.out.println(arrList);


/* Integer[] to Collection<Integer> */


    Integer[] intArr = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100 };
    Collection<Integer> c = Arrays.asList(intArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

Integer[] iArray = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(iArray));

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(list, iArray);
System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use IntStream of and boxed it to Integer after that sorted using reverseOrder comparator.

```
List<Integer> listItems = IntStream.of(arrayItems)
                .boxed()
                .sorted(Collections.reverseOrder())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This approach has the advantage of being more flexible, as you can use different collectors to create different types of lists (e.g., an ArrayList, a LinkedList, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic way to convert array to ArrayList

```
<T> ArrayList<T> toArrayList(Object o, Class<T> type){
    ArrayList<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < Array.getLength(o); i++) {
        //noinspection unchecked
        objects.add((T) Array.get(o, i));
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Usage

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = toArrayList(new int[]{1,2,3}, Integer.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Arrays.stream(ints).forEach(list::add);
```

Comment: @TomerShetah the statement is self explanatory. I expect reader to have a minimal understanding of Java Stream API.