# Java: Why isn't autoboxing happening here?

Tags: java, generics, types, autoboxing

This gives me an error:

```
int[] l = new int[] {0, 2, 192, -1, 3, 9, 2, 2};
int[] l2 = new int[] {9001, 7, 21, 4, -3, 11, 10, 10};
int[] l3 = new int[] {5, 5, 5, 64, 21, 12, 13, 200};

Set<List<Integer>> lists = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();
lists.add(Arrays.asList(l));
```

> Eclipse: The method `add(List<Integer>)` in the type `Set<List<Integer>>` is not applicable for the arguments (`List<int[]>`)

I thought `int` was supposed to be autoboxed to `Integer`?

Comment: Oh man you name a set object as list !!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Although int is autoboxed to Integer, int[] is not Autoboxed to Integer[].

The arrays are not boxed, just the types themselves.

See this: [How to convert int[] into List<Integer> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java) for workarounds and the underlying reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It will autobox from

```
Integer i = 1
int ii = i;
```

But, you are trying to convert an array, and when it tries to put an array of primitives as an array of objects they are different.