# Android findViewWithTag using int[] as view tag

Tags: android, view, tags

I want to bind some information by attaching tags to a view. So when the view is clicked I can retrieve this information with its tag. However, I meet problem when using an int array as the tag.
I save two integers by following samples:

```
int arr=[x,y];
view.setTag(arr);
parentView.addView(view);//parentView is a list/LinearLayout of such views
```

Later, when I want to find the view using

```
int tmp=[i, j];//i=x, j=y in values
View target=parentView.findViewWithTag(tmp);
```

The returned `target` is `null`. Why does it not return the correct view?

Edit:

I'm not sure if it's because of object reference and comparison issue. I tried to combine integers `x` and `y` into a string like `"x,y"`, and search the view like `parentView.findViewWithTag("x,y")` and it can find the view.

Comment: if you are dealing with arrays - the comparison is between their references not their values (new object with same values will return false because it differ in reference from other object). how about creating a custom view with custom attributes? http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

Comment: Moreover, I cannot find `findViewByTag()` on `View` or `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @CommonsWare That's findView*WITH*Tag()

Comment: @ymz I also doubt it's because the object reference issue. But Android view's tag can be an Object (e.g., a customized class), right? Then how to realize findViewWithTag(object) in this case?

Comment: Ah, I see. I haven't used that in ~5 years, and had forgotten they switched "by" with "with". However, [since `int[]` is not going to be autoboxed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1770906/115145), I have no idea what your tag is winding up as. I would recommend that you use actual objects, not arrays of primitives, as your tag. "it can find the view" -- and hence this demonstrates the point.

Comment: @CommonsWare OK, that could be a reason. Will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although didn't do verification experiments, a guess is mentioned by @CommonsWare. And real objects should solve the problem.