# Can I convert array of integer to List<int> or List<Integer> by Arrays.asList(array)?

Tags: java, collections

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should)
>   [How to convert int[] into List<Integer> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)

Or must I refactor int[] to Integer[] ?

Comment: Yes. Or don't use Arrays.asList()

Answer (score 2):

1. You can't have `List<int>`
2. `Arrays.asList(array);` will return you List with type T of (passed array)

You can have something like

```
  Integer[] a = new Integer[]{1,2,3};
  List<Integer> lst = Arrays.asList(a);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this way

```
Integer[] a ={1,2,4};

List<Integer> intList =  Arrays.asList(a);

System.out.println(intList);
```

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(array)` returns a *List-type* view on the array. So you can use the `List` interface to access the values of the wrapped array of java primitives.

Now what happens if we pass an array of java Objects and an array of java primitive values? The method takes a variable number of java objects. A java primitive is *not* an object. Java could use autoboxing to create wrapper instances, **but** in this case, it will take the array itself as an java object. So we end up like this:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3}));
List<int[]>   list2 = Arrays.asList(new int[]{1,2,3}));
```

The first collection holds the integer values, the second one the `int[]` array. No autoboxing here.

So *if* you want to convert an array of java primitives to a `List`, you **can't** use `Arrays.asList`, because it will simply return a `List` that contains just one item: the array.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :

From the comment below from develman, java 6 has support to return `List<>` object for same method

OLD ANSWER :

`Arrays.asList(array)` returns you a `java.util.List` object.

Comment: Java6 does it. Check current API: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a array of Integers then you can use Arrays.asList() to get a List of Integers:

```
Integer[] inters = new Integer[5];
List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(inters);
```