# (Un)boxing primitive arrays in Java

Tags: java, android, collections, boxing

in the Android Java world, is there a straighforward (ideally one-call) way to convert an array of `int` to an `ArrayList<Integer>` and back? Calling `toArray()` on the ArrayList returns an array of `Integer` - not quite what I want.

I can easily do that by hand with a loop (already did, in fact). I'm wondering if the library/language supports the same.

EDIT: thanks all, I already wrote my own boxer and unboxer. I'm just surprised the language/RTL designers didn't think of it themselves, especially with primitive types being by design ineligible for collections.

Comment: Core Java does not.  I'm sure someone can provide a link to a 3rd party library that can do it for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert int\[\] into List<Integer> in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44297189/how-to-collect-the-results-of-a-stream-in-a-primitive-array

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Boxing and unboxing (without special libraries):

```
// Necessary Imports:
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

// Integers:
int[] primitives = {1, 2, 3};
Integer[] boxed = Arrays.stream(primitives).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new);
int[] unboxed = Arrays.stream(boxed).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();

// Doubles:
double[] primitives = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
Double[] boxed = Arrays.stream(primitives).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new);
double[] unboxed = Arrays.stream(boxed).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
```

Note that this requires *Java 8* ([Stream Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html)).

For anyone unaware of what the `::` means, it's used to make a [Method Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Comment: What about `byte` and `Byte`? It seems there is no `mapToByte`.

Comment: @Anakhand I haven't been doing Java dev anymore for the past few years, but you might find this helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class

Answer (score 13):

Using [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava) ([Ints.asList(int...)](https://guava.dev/releases/32.1.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList(int...)) and [Ints.toArray(Collection<Integer>)](https://guava.dev/releases/32.1.2-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#toArray(java.util.Collection))):

```
int[] intArray = ...
List<Integer> intArrayAsList = Ints.asList(intArray);
int[] intArray2 = Ints.toArray(intArrayAsList);
```

Note that like `Arrays.asList`, `Ints.asList` returns a list that is a *view* of the given array. You can't add to or remove from it, but you can `set` the value at a specific index. You can also copy it to a new `ArrayList` if you want:

```
List<Integer> arrayList = Lists.newArrayList(Ints.asList(intArray));
```

Guava has the same methods for all primitive types.

Comment: I'm not introducing a new dependency into the project for the sake of a three line function I could write in my sleep.

Answer (score 4):

If you create a utility method, that would be a one call conversion. Perhaps, in your case, that would be better than adding a whole library (of which you might just use one function), although that should be too much burden for your app.

Here's the [source code](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html#toPrimitive%28Integer,%20int%29) for the h3xStream answer (glad it uses Apache license) ;)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find a solution in *Java 8* :

```
import java.util.Arrays;
...
double[] columnsValue = {...};
Double[] values = Arrays.stream(columnsValue).boxed().toArray(Double[]::new);
```

I can't explain what `Double[]::new` means exactly, because I didn't know this feature of *Java 8* before (in fact, *IntelliJ IDEA* wrote this for me), but it looks like it is doing `new Double(double)` on every element of the array.

***Please note** : I tested this only on desktop, I don't know if it works in Android.*

Comment: What you're doing there is actually only *boxing* (converting a primitive to its corresponding wrapper class), not *unboxing* (converting from a wrapper class to its corresponding primitive).