# Why ByteArrayOutputStream.close() throws IOException?

Tags: java, stream, bytearrayoutputstream

Why `ByteArrayOutputStream`.`close` is declared with `throws IOException`?
First, de facto it can't throw anything, because its body is empty. Second, de jure it can't throw anything, because its documentation says "closing a ByteArrayOutputStream has no effect".

Isn't this (non-important, but still) a little mistake?

Yes, I understand that its superclass `OutputStream` implements `Closable`, the `close` method of which is allowed to throw `IOException`. But nobody forbids to override it (in `ByteArrayOutputStream`) with `close` method with no throw specification. (Even if overriding a more-throwing method with a less-throwing method was forbidden in some ancient versions of Java, changing `ByteArrayOutputStream`.`close` definition *now* won't be incompatible change.)

Comment: if the definition was changed, existing codes which catch IOException will get compile error `Unreachable catch block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body`.

Comment: @saka1029: I think, you are on the right track.

Comment: @saka1029, you're right (I thought it would cause warning, not error).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most plausible explanation (besides oversight) is compatibility. Back in Java 1.1, `ByteArrayOutputStream` [did not override `close()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20011102022450/http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.1/docs/api/java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.html), so it inherited the method from `OutputStream` which declares `IOException`. Back then, it might have been an oversight. Perhaps, the developers thought that this is unnecessary as nobody is going to call `close()` on a `ByteArrayOutputStream` anyway. But the documentation lacks an explicit statement about calling `close()` being unnecessary.

Since Java 1.2 aka Java 2, `ByteArrayOutputStream` [does override `close()`](http://web.archive.org/web/20011117000235/http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.2/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#close()). But removing the `throws` clause would cause code calling `close()` on a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and catching the checked `IOException` to produce a compile-time error when the exception is not thrown at any other place within the `try` block. Since this doesn’t affect the binary compatibility, it might look strange considering how much changes with more impact were made on the source code level since then.

But this decision was made a long time age. It’s also unclear, why the override was added at all, as the inherited no-op was sufficient and the override doesn’t change the signature and also doesn’t contain a useful documentation improvement in that version, i.e. no clarification about `close()` being unnecessary. The most plausible explanation is that it was added with the intent of removing the `throws` clause, but then it was detected that the incompatibility was an issue with certain existing code.

In the end, it’s not really important to remove it. If your compile-time type is `ByteArrayOutputStream`, you know that you don’t need to call `close()`. In all other cases, i.e. if the compile-time type is the more general `OutputStream`, you have to `close()` and handle the declared `IOException`…

Comment: I understand, that it’s not really important to remove it.

Comment: Actually, the main part of the answer was introduced by @saka1029: I didn't know that *removing* a throws clause really can introduce incompatibilities. I think that fact (that removing a throws clause can introduce source incompatibilities; that "Unreachable catch block for …" is an error, not a warning) is a mistake per se.

Comment: @saka1029's statement is a comment (not an answer), so I can't accept it (despite it appeared first and is laconic, so I'd like to do it very much).