# when i use Java 8 Stream.of primitive type, the result is confused

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
    byte[] a = {1,2,3};
    System.out.println(Stream.of(a).count());

    Byte[] b = {1,2,3};
    System.out.println(Stream.of(b).count());
```

the result is 1 and 3, why?

Comment: One way to create a stream of Bytes can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class/58520704#58520704)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Stream.of` only accepts Objects as its arguments. A `byte` isn't an Object, but a `byte` array is. If `a` is an array of `byte`, then `Stream.of(a)` can only mean "stream of this one object, which is an array".

If you have a `Byte[]` array, then each element of the array is an object, so the compiler can guess that's what you mean.

There is information here about how you can stream a byte array:
[In Java 8, is there a ByteStream class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class)

Comment: @yijiang So it will.

Comment: but your explanation help me, 3Q.

Answer (score 3):

For primitive arrays you should be using primitive streams, but unfortunately there is no `ByteStream`. If you change your `byte[]` to `int[]`, you could write :

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
System.out.println(IntStream.of(a).count());
```

Otherwise you get a `Stream<byte[]>` whose single element is the input array, since both `static<T> Stream<T> of(T t)` and `static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values)` expect a reference type as the `Stream` element, so when you pass a primitive array, the only available reference type is the array itself.

In your `System.out.println(Stream.of(b).count());` case, `b` is an array of reference types, so `static<T> Stream<T> of(T... values)` is used to produce a `Stream<Byte>` of 3 elements.

Comment: @yijiang I missed that. I didn't consider that `byte[]` can't be automatically converted to `int[]`. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: 3Q for your explanation.