# Java 8 Streams : The method boxed() is undefined for the type Stream<Byte>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, boxing

I am trying to convert an array of bytes to a `LinkedList<Byte>`:

```
//data is of type byte[]
List<Byte> list = Arrays.stream(toObjects(data)).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());

Byte[] toObjects(byte[] bytesPrim) {
    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[bytesPrim.length];
    Arrays.setAll(bytes, n -> bytesPrim[n]);

    return bytes;
}
```

The first line raises an error message saying:

> The method `boxed()` is undefined for the type `Stream<Byte>`.

Any idea why am I getting this error message and how to circumvent this problem please?

Comment: You can't box a stream that's already of boxed objects. =)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Should I then kick out the call for boxed() method?

Comment: Well what do you expect it to do? Which method do you *expect* it to be calling? Note that your array type is already `Byte[]`, not `byte[]`.

Comment: Since your `toObjects` method already returns a `Byte[]`, there is no need for this stream operation at all. You can simply use `List<Byte> list = Arrays.asList(toObjects(data));`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The method `boxed()` is designed only for streams of some primitive types (`IntStream`, `DoubleStream`, and `LongStream`) to box each primitive value of the stream into the corresponding wrapper class (`Integer`, `Double`, and `Long` respectively).

The expression `Arrays.stream(toObjects(data))` returns a `Stream<Byte>` which is already boxed since [there is no such thing as a `ByteStream` class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class).

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you don't need the `boxed()` method there - you already do it yourself in `toObjects()` which converts it to `Byte`s.

Second thing, there's no such method for bytes. it exists for ints, doubles, but not bytes. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class)

Answer (score 0):

For what you want to do you can directly use `Arrays.asList(toObjects(data))`since `toObjects(data)` is of type `Byte[]`.
Alternatively if you really want to use Streams, then `Stream.of(toObjects(data)).collect(Collectors.toList())` should do the trick.