# Convert Java java.util.Stream<Byte> to a byte array

Tags: java

I need to convert a stream (Java 8 stream, not InputStream) into a byte array.

I have tried using `toArray` method of `Stream`, but it doesn't accept `byte[]::new`, as `byte` is a primitive type.

I also tried using `toArray` method of `IntStream`, but it doesn't accept arguments, it assumes you want to get `int[]` back.

It's possible to convert a stream to a list or an array of boxed `Byte` types, and then convert it to `byte[]`, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Edit: Added code, if that helps understanding the question. This doesn't compile, it's just pseudo-code. If it helps, you can also consider `IntStream` to be `Stream<Byte>`, for my purposes it doesn't matter.

```
byte[] getArray(IntStream stream) {
    return stream.toArray();
}
```

Comment: How about writing the bytes into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and returning that from the stream?

Comment: What type of objects does the `Stream` contain?

Comment: show us some code? Will help to get an idea about what you want to try.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class

Comment: Why do you think you can convert the stream to a byte array? It would require serialization at the minimum.

Comment: @daniu `int` or `Integer`, but it doesn't really matter, whatever works for the solution (question of using `map` vs `mapToObj`).

Comment: @Kayaman Because Java provides `toArray` methods for `IntStream`, `LongStream`, `DoubleStream` and `Stream<T>`. It seems like there should be a way to convert to `byte[]`.

Comment: Well it might seem like that to someone with no understanding about Java. You can't just convert an object to `byte[]`, let alone a stream of objects. What do you think you'd do with those bytes?

Comment: @Kayaman I know that they aren't represented the same way, so copying is needed, but that's fine. What I have is `Stream<Byte>` (or `IntStream`).

Comment: Why do you have a `Stream<Byte>` and not an `InputStream`? Did someone use `Stream<Byte>` because they didn't really understand Java 8 streams? Because that's the only reason I could think of.

Comment: @Kayaman Because it comes from a stream over a collection which did some other transformations on a value.

Comment: Sounds like bad design. A `Stream<Byte>` is not a byte stream.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can make `byte[]` from the original stream's individual entries and then concatenate them in the end.

```
static byte[] <T> toByteArray(Stream<T> stream, Function<T, byte[]> transform) {
    Stream<byte[]> arrayStream = stream.map(transform);
    arrayStream.collect(concatArrays);
}
```

However, the only implementation I can think of for a `concatArrays` Collector would be:

- maintain a `byte[]` containing the already collected data
- for each entry of the Stream, expand it to accomodate the new entry
- use `System.arraycopy` to combine the arrays

I'd expect you'd be better off with your "boxing to `Byte` and then convert" in almost all cases.