# Casting double[] to byte[] using stream in Java

Tags: java, arrays, casting, byte, java-stream

Hey I'm working on an app that uses Paho mqtt

Now I'm trying to cast the contents of a couple of objects to byte arrays so I can send them to the broker. There are a couple of different objects that all adhere to a abstract class, but the one I started with contains a double[]

Here's the function I'm trying to implement:

```
    @Override
public byte[] getBytes() {

    return Arrays.stream(driveVector).map(d -> Double.valueOf(d).byteValue()).toArray();
}
```

I thought this would work, but I get an error that the return value is a double[]

I think I either don't understand the map method or I'm goin about this all wrong in general (I looked at the ByteBuffer class, but it seems like a pain to implement this with it)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to convert each `double` to a single `byte`, or to the 8 bytes that make it up?

Comment: There is no ByteStream hence the `map` operation will yield a `DoubleStream` and therefore you're getting back a `double[]` when you call `toArray()`

Comment: *"or I'm goin about this all wrong in general"* You are. Don't use streams. A normal `for` loop of copying values from `double[]` to `byte[]` would do it, and run much faster too.

Comment: *"I don't understand the map method"* The [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#map(java.util.function.DoubleUnaryOperator)) method of `DoubleStream` maps to another `DoubleStream`. You can use `mapToInt​`, `mapToLong`, or `mapToObj` if you want a different type of stream, but there is no `mapToByte`.

Comment: Re-opened, since I don't think it's a duplicate of [In Java 8, is there a ByteStream class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32459683/5221149)

Comment: In any case, don't use `Double.valueOf(d).byteValue()`: simply use `(byte) d`, to avoid the unnecessary boxing.

Comment: @Mureinik Yes I was trying to get the 8 bytes that make it up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ByteBuffer for it:

```
double[] doubles = new double[] {1,2,3,4,5};
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(doubles.length * Double.BYTES);
Arrays.stream(doubles).forEach(buffer::putDouble);
buffer.array();
```

Comment: For some reason I was trying to avoid this, but thanks. I guess this is the best answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't cast a `double[]` to a `byte[]` for the fundamental reason that they are unrelated types, and you can only cast between related types.

Casts in Java, unlike, say, C++, don't actually create a new object: they are merely a way to the compiler "I know more about the type of this object than you; trust me." For example, you might know that a variable of type `Object` actually holds a reference to a `String`, something which the compiler cannot know; in that case, you can cast the reference.

You can, however, construct a new array:

```
byte[] output = new byte[input.length];
for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {
  output[j] = (byte) input[j];
}
```

There is no way to do this with streams. Or rather, there is, in that you could crowbar this code into a stream operation on a `Stream<double[]>`, say; but involving streams like that clearly adds no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Java Streams is not the right tool here, especially not since there is no `ByteStream` in Java.

Your method can be implemented as a simple `for` loop.

```
@Override
public byte[] getBytes() {
    byte[] arr = new byte[driveVector.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        arr[i] = (byte) driveVector[i];
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my MQTT application I read a single double value and post that to the broker. However, there is no real difference between a single and an array of doubles. The client needs to know the array length, while with a single value it always knows there is one.

I'm confident that you can adapt my code to writing multiple values, adapt the `toMessage` to write multiple `double` values.

```
public abstract class SensorMonitor {
  protected final MqttAsyncClient client;
  protected final String topic;
  protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()); 
  private final ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(8);
  private final DataOutputStream dataOut = new DataOutputStream(byteOut);

  public SensorMonitor(MqttAsyncClient mqttClient, String topic) {
    this.client = mqttClient;
    this.topic = topic;
  }

  public void start(ScheduledExecutorService service) {
    service.scheduleWithFixedDelay(this::publish, 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  protected void publish() {
    try {
        MqttMessage message = toMessage(readNewValue());
        client.publish(topic, message);

    } catch (MqttException | IOException e) {
        logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Could not publish message", e);
    }
  }

  private MqttMessage toMessage(double value) throws IOException {
    byteOut.reset();
    dataOut.writeDouble(value);
    return new MqttMessage(byteOut.toByteArray());
  }

  protected abstract double readNewValue();
}
```

The `DataOutputStream.writeDouble` uses [`Double.doubleToLongBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) to create a IEEE 754 floating-point "double format" bit layout.

In my case I could pre-alloc and reuse the `byteOut` output stream as I knew upfront the needed size of the `byte[]`.