# Create a Stream from a byte[] to a primitive byte Stream

Tags: java

I have a `byte[]` and I want to make a byte stream.

For `int[]` and `long` and `double`, I see methods in the Arrays class:

```
Arrays.stream(int[] array)
Arrays.stream(long[] array)
Arrays.stream(double[] array)
```

However, I don't see any for a method `Arrays.stream(byte[] array)`.

What then is the easiest and most concise way to then get a stream of byte primitives as actual bytes?

I need to do transformations on byte[]'s and I need a Stream of bytes to do it using all the Stream functions (and no, I don't want to convert them all to ints.)

Who has a nice solution?

PS. Someone else is providing me the byte[] from a microcontroller API ... So I don't want to play with some other data type if not necessary.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with boxing the bytes to a `Stream<Byte>`? The boxing [is cached](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#valueOf-byte-), so it doesn't cost you anything more than an index lookup. Then you can work with the Bytes using all of the Stream stuff, and Java will auto-unbox and re-box them as needed for you.

Comment: @yshavit That's fine. But it requires an intermediate step to create another array and then move the `byte` to a `Byte`. Why not post and answer? Let's see your full solution.

Comment: I don't think this is a dupe of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class). That question has a narrow scope: yes or no, does a ByteStream exist. This question asks what can be done about it.

Comment: @yshavit  I agree.  I'm glad it was reopened.

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with the stream, you could use the old `new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));` instead

Comment: I need to do Stream operations. The InputStream types do not offer a Stream conversion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `Stream<Byte>` is about as good as a ByteStream of primitives would be, since [`Byte#valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#valueOf-byte-) returns cached instances of the boxed values (and the compiler handles boxing and unboxing for you). So then the only trick is to turn your `byte[]` into a `Stream<Byte>`.

One way to do that would be to create an `IntStream` of indexes, and then map those indexes into lookups into your `byte[]`:

```
byte[] byteArray = "hello".getBytes();
Stream<Byte> byteStream = IntStream.range(0, byteArray.length)
    .mapToObj(i -> byteArray[i]);
```

I don't know of any helper method in the JDK that does this for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```
  byte[] a = { 1, 2, 3, 4
  };
   
  byteStream(a).forEach(System.out::println);


  public static IntStream byteStream(byte[] a) {
     return IntStream.range(0, a.length).map(idx -> a[idx]);
  }

  public static byte[] toByteArray(IntStream b) {
      Byte[] barray = b.mapToObj(a ->(byte)( a & 0xFF)).toArray(Byte[]::new);
      byte[] ret = new byte[barray.length];
      int i = 0;
      for(byte byt : barray) {
          ret[i++] = byt;
      }
  }
```

Otherwise you may need to use Steam with Byte since the primitive implementations of byte, float, and short don't exist.  I believe `Guava` supports byte streams.

Comment: `IntStream.range(0, a.length).map(idx -> a[idx]);` I like that. It isn't too complicated either!

Comment: @TheCoordinator  But fair warning.  It has it's limitations.  It is still an Intstream and there is no easy way to get it back into a primitive byte array.

Comment: sadly, this fails with two runtime errors (both `ArrayStoreException`s) - on `toArray(Byte[]::new)` and ( if you provide a correct `Byte[]` in a different way) `arraycopy` which doesn't handle objects (via unboxing) automatically

Comment: @almondandapricot Yep.  I believe it is fixed.  Had to alter the mapping and used a for loop to do the copying.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
byte[] byteArray = "Hello World".getBytes();

    Stream.Builder<Byte> builder = Stream.builder();
    for (int i = 0; i < byteArray.length; i++) {
        builder.add(byteArray[i]);
    }
    Stream<Byte> stream = builder.build();

    stream.forEach(str -> System.out.print(str + " ")); 

    /*for(Object b : stream.toArray()){
        String a= new String(new byte[]{(byte)b});
        System.out.println(a);
    }*/
```