# Why does Stream.Builder have both add and accept methods?

Tags: java, java-stream

I was using a [`Stream.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html) and I stumbled upon the fact that this interface has both the methods `accept(T t)` and `add(T t)`. The only difference is that the former returns `void` and the latter returns a `Stream.Builder`.

The documentation even mentions these methods to have the same default implementation:

> The default implementation behaves as if:
>
> ```
> accept(t)
> return this;
> ```

<sup>Note that they forgot a semicolon, but that's another story.</sup>

My question is: *why* do they have two methods to add something to the stream builder? I think this clutters the API, and I thought they wanted to [avoid that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32459683/in-java-8-is-there-a-bytestream-class).

Is there any compelling reason to do so?

Comment: Some static code analyzation tools (IntelliJ in some capacity I reckon, or was it Checkstyle?) complain when you call a method with return type without assigning that return type to a variable, thus the `void` one. And the one with the return type can be used to chain calls in a single line of course.

Comment: `accept` stems from being a `Consumer<T>` and `add` allows the typical chained call (fluent style).

Comment: @Sweeper I meant https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html#accept(T) - Conffusion's answer explains it better.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My guess:

[`Stream.Builder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.Builder.html) extends `Consumer<T>` so it must implement the `accept(T)` method.

But `accept(T)` returns `void`, so I think they added `add(T)` for convenience: methods in a builder pattern implementation often return `this` to be able to chain the building and finally call `build()`.

Comment: Additionally, 'add' is the right name when treating the streambuilder as a builder (I bet if I interview 100 devs about 'what would you call the method on a stream building object, 99 of them would say 'add', and not one would say 'accept'). If you _treat_ that builder as a consumer, then from that quite different viewpoint, 'accept' all of a sudden is sensible.

Comment: I see, the `void accept` is inherited from `Consumer`. That makes sense to me.

Comment: But for using it as a `Consumer`, it would suffice to do `.callWithConsumer(builder::add)`, no need to make it a `Consumer` in the first place. But they chose to do so, so they must implement it.