# convert a double array to float list and found lambda ignored floating point type conversion

Tags: java-8

`double[]` is converted to a `List<Float>`, I thought Streams map operation could convert a double stream to a float stream, but no... it is still double stream. In the following 2 conversions, the first works, as v.floatValue() becomes float type, but (float) v still is double type. Why?

```
List<Float> collect = Arrays.stream(vec).boxed().map(v -> v.floatValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

(float)v is still double. `Required List<Float>, provided List<Double>`

```
List<Float> collect2 = Arrays.stream(vec).map(v -> (float) v).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second doesn't work because [`DoubleStream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#map-java.util.function.DoubleUnaryOperator-) always returns a `DoubleStream`. Its parameter is a `DoubleUnaryOperator`, which is a function that takes a `double` and returns a `double`.

You happen to be able to pass the lambda `v -> (float) v` to `map` because there is an implicit conversion that converts `float` to `double`. As a result, `v -> (float) v` still counts as "a function that takes a `double` and returns a `double`". You are essentially saying `v -> (double)(float) v`.

Note that there is no `FloatStream` in the standard library (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32459764/5133585) for why), so you cannot have a stream of primitive `float`s as one of your intermediate steps, like what you are trying to do in your second code snippet.

An alternative to your first approach would be to use `mapToObj`, directly mapping `double` to `Float`:

```
Arrays.stream(vec).mapToObj(v -> (float)v).toList()
```

Comment: please also explain why `Arrays.stream(vec).boxed().map(Double::floatValue).collect(Collectors.toList())` is a `List<Float>`, since there is no `FloatStream`, why `map(v -> v.floatValue)` is not treated as `map(v -> (double) v.floatValue)`?

Comment: @Tiina There is no `FloatStream` for primitive `float`s, but there is `Stream<Float>`, and that's what you get from using `.boxed().map(Double::floatValue)`. `boxed` makes `Stream<Double>`, and unlike `DoubleStream.map`, `Stream<Double>.map` can transform the elements to other reference types.

Comment: @Tiina `Stream<Float>` is also the type that `.mapToObj(v -> (float)v)` returns.