# How to collect the results of a Stream in a primitive array?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, primitive

I'm trying to convert 2D list to a 2D `int` array. However, it seems I can only collect objects, not primitives.

When I do:

```
data.stream().map(l -> l.stream().toArray(int[]::new)).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

I get the compile-time error `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R> map(Function<? super T,? extends R>)`.

However, if I change `int[]` to `Integer[]`, it compiles. How can I get it to just use `int`?

Comment: For the lambda, try `l.stream().mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray()`

Comment: How can I collect the results of this though? That just performs operations on the Stream without storing the results.

Comment: My suggestion handles the incorrect lambda you were using. It will collect properly now.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use [`mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) method to produce a stream of primitive integers:

```
int[][] res = data.stream().map(l -> l.stream().mapToInt(v -> v).toArray()).toArray(int[][]::new);
```

The inner `toArray` call no longer needs `int[]::new`, because `IntStream` produces `int[]`.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/RiKRko)