# The best way to transform int[] to List<Integer> in Java?

Tags: java, generics, collections

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create ArrayList (ArrayList<T>) from array (T[]) in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/157944/how-to-create-arraylist-arraylistt-from-array-t-in-java)

How to implement this method:

```
List<Integer> toList(int[] integers) {
    ???
    //return Arrays.asList(integers); doesn't work
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for the second part of this question, before I edit it out?

Comment: @DJClayworth: I think, no. I've already flagged the question and explaned that I met some difficulties during submitting this question.

Comment: @Merlyn: Not a duplicate. Primitive arrays are different from Object arrays

Comment: @Alexander: Wow.  That's gross :)  I can't rescind my vote, so I'll just delete my comment.

Comment: Instead of being a duplicate of the given question, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/1073919/1108305.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's probably a built-in method to do it somewhere* (as you note, `Arrays.asList` won't work as it expects an `Integer[]` rather than an `int[]`).

I don't know the Java libraries well enough to tell you where that is. But writing your own is quite simple:

```
public static List<Integer> createList(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        list.add(array[i]);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Obviously one downside of this is that you can't do it generically. You'll have to write a separate `createList` method for each autoboxed primitive type you want.

<sub>*And if there isn't, I *really* wonder why not.</sub>

Comment: For efficiency's sake, i might recommend `new ArrayList<Integer>(array.length)`.  Should keep Java from having to resize the collection to add elements.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Integer> asList(final int[] integers) {
    return new AbstractList<Integer>() {
        public Integer get(int index) {
            return integers[index];
        }

        public int size() {
            return integers.length;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: There are a couple of big issues: (1) the list is backed by the array -- that is, if the array elements change, the list elements will too.  (2) For larger ints, you'll get back a different Integer each time -- that is, you can not have any expectation of reference equality.  Either of those might or might not be an issue, but they're semi-surprising behavior.  Before i add (3), can Java actually do closures like that?

Comment: @cHao: 3. Yes, Java can do closures like that!

Comment: Technically this should then be named **as** List, at least when assuming that Java follows the same naming convention as .NET in this regard (*as* providing a differently-typed view on the same collection while *to* actually doing a conversion).

Comment: These are not closures. They are anonymous classes.

Comment: Just to add one more thing: whenever you are accessing this `List`, conversion from _`int` to `Integer`_ happens which is very slow. Don't do what this answer is recommending

Comment: @Senthess: It's an anonymous class with methods that refer to a local variable from the context it's created in.  That's pretty much the definition of a closure, at least in the way Java could do it.

Comment: invoking `addAll(...)` on such a list and then `get(...)` would result in odd behavior since `get(...)` only is able to access the numbers from the `int[]`. In short: although it looks neat, I wouldn't recommend doing it like this.

Comment: I remember when I saw this for the first time in Java. It's kind of sad, actually: they decided to do *big*-time support for anonymous classes, allowing you to implement an entire interface on the fly. But it involves so much typing that doing simple stuff like a one-line C#-style lambda isn't possible.

Comment: @Op De Cirkel: That depends on the use. This will be faster if not all Integers in the list are accessed. And in most cases the performance difference will be too small to matter anyway.

Comment: @cHao: That it's backed by the array is a much a feature as an issue. It depends on the use.

Comment: @Bart Kiers: This list does not support `addAll()`, since `AbstractList#set(int, Integer)` is not overridden, so no, it would not result in odd behaviour. The behaviour is well-defined. That the list should be modifiable wasn't a requirement, and it might be considered a feature that it's not, depending on the use.

Comment: Also, `AbstractList#add(int, Integer)`

Comment: @Christoffer, ah, yes, then there's no problem: I thought `add(...)` was implemented in `AbstractList`. My bad, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2):

Use commons-lang3 `org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils.toObject(<yout int array>)` and then `java.util.Arrays.asList(<>)`

`ArrayUtils.toObject()` will *copy* the array, and `Array.asList()` will simply create list that is backed by new array.

```
int[] a = {1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> aI = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(a));
```

**EDIT:** This wont work if you want to `add()` new elements (*resize*) though the list *interface*, if you want to be able to add new elements, you can use `new ArrayList()`, but this will create one more copy.

Comment: You can do it directly with `List<Integer> xValues = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 150, 160, 175, 165, 165 });`

Comment: @AlexanderPacha Definitely, it works with an `Integer[]` literal, but not with an existing `int[]`. It can not be placed in the method skeleton from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Integer> toList(int[] integers) {
    // Initialize result's size to length of the incoming array
    // this way it will not require reallocations
    ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>( integers.length );

    for ( int cur: integers )
    {
        result.add( Integer.valueOf( cur ) );
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a quick way to do it unfortunately. I believe you will have to iterate the array and add it one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Listing {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

   int[] integers = {1,2,3,4};

   java.util.List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  for (int i=0; i< integers.length; i++)
  {
      list.add(integers[i]);
  }
  System.out.println(list);
}
}
```

Tested and working as expected!