# Java (specifically Netbeans and JForms): Checking duplicates in each line of 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans, duplicates, 2d

I am doing a Lotto application in a jForm/GUI in Netbeans with 3 rows of 5 numbers, and I don't want duplicates to be allowed on each line. To have one number on line 1 and the same on line 3 is OK, but to have those numbers on the same line is not OK.

The only way I can think of doing it that I know will work is to hard code it, and preferably, I don't want that.

I have tried:

```
    boolean dup = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < num[0].length){ //loop through columns
     for (i = 0; i < num.length-1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < inArray.length; j++){
          if (num[k][i] == num[k][j]){
            dup = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

and this:

```
    public static boolean hasDuplicates(int [][] num) {
        for (int row = 0; row < num.length; row++) {
            int curRow = num[row];
           Set set = Sets.newHashSet(Arrays.asList(curRow));
            if (set.size() < curRow.length) {
               return true;
           }
       }
        return false;
   }
```

I have also looked at other coding extensively and I can't get one that works.

The exact thing I'm trying to do is:

Get user's input for  three lines of Lotto via text field, check each line for duplicates, print to a jLabel if it's a duplicate or leave the jLabel blank and run the rest of the code if there's no duplicates.

The current code I have is:

```
        private void playBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    num[0][0] = Integer.parseInt(line00Tf.getText());
    num[0][1] = Integer.parseInt(line01Tf.getText());
    num[0][2] = Integer.parseInt(line02Tf.getText());
    num[0][3] = Integer.parseInt(line03Tf.getText());
    num[0][4] = Integer.parseInt(line04Tf.getText());
    num[1][0] = Integer.parseInt(line10Tf.getText());
    num[1][1] = Integer.parseInt(line11Tf.getText());
    num[1][2] = Integer.parseInt(line12Tf.getText());
    num[1][3] = Integer.parseInt(line13Tf.getText());
    num[1][4] = Integer.parseInt(line14Tf.getText());
    num[2][0] = Integer.parseInt(line20Tf.getText());
    num[2][1] = Integer.parseInt(line21Tf.getText());
    num[2][2] = Integer.parseInt(line22Tf.getText());
    num[2][3] = Integer.parseInt(line23Tf.getText());
    num[2][4] = Integer.parseInt(line24Tf.getText());

        duplicateLbl.setText("");
        LottoPhase1 p1 = new LottoPhase1();
        p1.setNum(num);
        p1.createSecret();
        secret = p1.getSecret();
        p1.computeCheckInput();
        correctL1 = p1.getCorrectL1();
        correctL2 = p1.getCorrectL2();
        correctL3 = p1.getCorrectL3();

        //prints secret to output
        System.out.println("Phase 1 Main Secret: " + Arrays.toString(secret));
        System.out.println();


        displayResults0Lbl.setText(Integer.toString(secret[0]) + ", " + Integer.toString(secret[1]) + ", " + Integer.toString(secret[2]) + ", " + Integer.toString(secret[3]) + ", " + Integer.toString(secret[4]));

        matched1NumLbl.setText(Integer.toString(correctL1));
        matched2NumLbl.setText(Integer.toString(correctL2));
        matched3NumLbl.setText(Integer.toString(correctL3));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates(int[][] num)
{
    boolean hasDuplicate  = false;
    // for each line in num
    for(int[] line : num)
    {
        // for every number in the row
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length && !hasDuplicate; i++)
        {
            // for every number in the row
            for(int j = 0; j < line.length; j++)
            {
                // if we are not comparing the same number
                if(i != j)
                {
                    // check for equality
                    if(line[i] == line[j])
                    {
                        hasDuplicate = true; // we have found a duplicate
                        break; // no need to keep checking; break the loop and return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return hasDuplicate;
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you. I had tried the others and they were not working, only this one worked. Thanks, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The second method has a couple of errors, for instance,

```
int curRow = num[row];
```

Should actually be:

```
int[] curRow = num[row];
```

Also, you appear to be using *Sets*, which probably comes from some library you're using *(Guava, Google Common, etc.)*. Assuming you were not using any library, you could change your code to something similar to:

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates(int [][] num) {
    for (int[] curRow : num) {
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (int n : curRow) {
            if (!set.add(n)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you're using Java 8, one way to remove the second for loop is by using a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html):

```
public static boolean hasDuplicates(int [][] num) {
    for (int[] curRow : num) {
        Set<Integer> set = IntStream.of(curRow).boxed().collect(Collectors.toSet());
        if (set.size() < curRow.length) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Other alternatives to the Stream can be found in threads like [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030661/java-int-array-to-hashsetinteger).
Testing with the following input produces what I think you would expect:

```
int[][] testA = {{0,1,2,3,4}, {0,1,2,3,4}, {0,1,2,3,4}}; //false
int[][] testB = {{0,1,2,3,4}, {0,2,2,3,4}, {0,1,2,3,4}}; //true
int[][] testC = {{0,1,2,3,4}, {0,1,2,3,4}, {0,4,3,3,4}}; //true
int[][] testD = {{0,1,2,3,4}, {5,6,7,8,9}, {10,11,12,13,14}}; //false
```