# int[] to Hashset (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, java-8, set, java-stream

possible replica of [Java int[] array to HashSet<Integer>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030661/java-int-array-to-hashsetinteger) but badly answered so new question.

I have a set that I'm trying to declare :

```
int[] flattened = Arrays.stream(arcs).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(flattened));
```

---

but as the return type of `Arrays.asList` is a list itself, it cannot resolve. 
What would be the best method to turn a list of `int[]` into `Set<Integer>`

Comment: If you just changed your array to `Integer[] flattened` it would work fine. Your problem is with types. `HashSet` does take a `Collection` (and thus a `List`) as its constructor argument just fine.

Comment: By the way, if the integers in your set can only ever have small non-negative values (e.g. if all your values fall in the range 0..1024) then consider using `BitSet` instead of `Set<Integer>`.

Comment: I would like to change the title to be **List<int[]> to HashSet**, you already said in your question *What would be the best method to turn a list of int[] into Set<Integer>*!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it as a one-liner, like so:

```
Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(arcs).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

---

Updated: Jack comments below that Collectors.toSet() is not guaranteed to return a HashSet -- in practice I think it usually does, but no guarantees -- so it would be better to use:

```
Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(arcs).flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
  .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new HashSet<>()));
```

And as DodgyCodeException points, out, OP's sample had an additional problem I wasn't addressing, so tweak using this:

```
Set<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(arcs)
    .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
    .boxed() // <-- converts from IntStream to Stream<Integer>
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new HashSet<>()));
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to be an `HashSet` as per OP requirement, probably `.toCollection(() -> new HashSet<>())` is better

Comment: Fair enough. The implementation I'm using happens to use HashSet... I can add an elaboration to that effect.

Comment: @Jack Depends on what you consider OP requirements.  The question contains `Set<Integer> = …`, which I interpret as meaning a Set of Integer is required.

Comment: Won't work as `IntStream.collect` takes 3 arguments.

Comment: @VGR: well, the title of the question is `int[]` to `HashSet`, there's not much left to interpretation.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException I was assuming that OP's original code was mostly working... I don't know what `arcs` is, for example, so I'm not attempting to run. But this should get him closer.

Comment: Whatever `arcs` is, the call to `flatMapToInt` definitely produces an `IntStream` and not a `Stream`, so from there on, you know exactly what the type is.

Comment: so arcs is a int[][], and with collect(collectors.toC.....) i get a collect() in Instream cannot be applied to parameters

Comment: @entercaspa you need to either supply three parameters (as per the Javadoc) or call `.boxed()` before `.collect(...)`.

Comment: one second i must quickly look up what boxed does

Comment: marked as answer because i understood more of the methods due to discussion. thank you all for your help

Comment: @Holger I hope readers of your comment spot your typo ;-) (you meant HashSet, of course, and not HashMap)

Comment: Instead of `() -> new HashSet<>()` you can simply write `HashSet::new`.

Comment: @DodgyCodeException of course. I decided to comment again instead of letting it that wrong

Answer (score 5):

> ..What would be the best method to turn a **list of int[] into
>   Set**

In this case you can use :

```
List<int[]> arcs = ...;
Set<Integer> set = arcs.stream()
        .flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Example :

```
List<int[]> arcs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new int[]{1, 2, 3}, new int[]{3, 4, 6}));
```

Outputs

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
```

---

Note : as [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53009857/int-to-hashset-java#comment92923208_53009912) mention, to guaranteed the collection to be `HashSet` you can collect like so :

```
...
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new HashSet<>()));
```

Comment: Ditto as my other comment.