# Checking whether an element exist in an array

Tags: java

A simple Java code for checking whether an element exists in an array or not:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    static int[] numbers = {813, 907, 908, 909, 910};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number = 907;
        //Integer number = 907; // the same thing -- it's not found.
        boolean b = Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(number);
        System.out.println(b);  // => false
    }
}
```

1) Why doesn't it find 907 in the array?

2) If there is a better way of doing it, go ahead and share your knowledge.

UPDATE:

It was said that `asList` converts your `int[]` into a `List<int[]>` with a single member: the original list. However, I expect the following code to give me 1, but it gives me 5:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(numbers).size());
```

Comment: Have you tried using Integer number = 907; ?

Comment: Witch is your question?

Comment: doesn't "int" mean Integer?

Comment: No, `int` does not mean `Integer`. The first is a primitive type, the second is an object.

Comment: this approach is time-consuming, just try to run [threads](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616109/Java-Thread-Tutorial) to find your value, each [thread](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/07/java-thread-example.html#ai) search through one/some data in array, btw +1, nice question

Comment: @user2511414, WOW thats really a good idea, to use threads for that. :p

Comment: Is your array in fact sorted or is that only in your example?

Comment: *"However, I expect the following code to give me 1, but it gives me 5"* - I think you made a mistake.  When I added that statement to your program and ran it, it said "1".

Comment: @StephenC true: http://ideone.com/C3FaRC

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java, it explains why the conversion from `int[]` to `List<Integer>` doesn't work.  Tedd Hopp's answer should solve your problem in any case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is that `Arrays.asList(numbers)` isn't doing what you think. It is converting your `int[]` into a `List<int[]>` with a single member: the original list.

You can do a simple linear search or, if your `numbers` array is always sorted, use `Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, 907);` and test whether the result is negative (meaning not found).

Comment: **It is converting your int[] into a List<int[]> with a single member: the original list.** --sorry, I didn't get this.

Comment: `.asList(num)` means "as list". You should not expect a method called `.asList(num)` to return an array instead...

Comment: @MariusKavansky - Well, `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(numbers).size());` prints 1 for me. Are you sure you didn't change the declaration of `numbers` to `Integer[]`?

Answer (score 6):

Lists don't contain primitives, so Arrays.asList(int[]) will produce a `List` with one entry of type `int[]`.

This code works:

```
static Integer[] numbers = {813, 907, 908, 909, 910};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer number = 907;
    boolean b = Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(number);
    System.out.println(b);  // => false
}
```

For your question as what will `Arrays.asList(numbers)` contain as long as it is an `int[]`:

This code:

```
static int[] numbers = {813, 907, 908, 909, 910};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int number = 907;
    List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);

    boolean b = list.contains(number);
    System.out.println(b);  // => false
    System.out.println("list: " + list);
    for(int[] next : list) {
        System.out.println("content: " + Arrays.toString(next));
    }
}
```

has this result:

```
false
list: [[I@da89a7]
content: [813, 907, 908, 909, 910]
```

As you can see, the `list` contains one element of type `int[]` (the `[[I` indicate the `int[]`). It has the elements that were initially created.

Comment: **with one entry of type int[]** -- what will the value of this entry?

Comment: @MariusKavansky The original array. I will update my answer to explain.

Answer (score 2):

With guava [`ImmutableSet`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableSet.html):

```
public class Main {

    private static final Set<Integer> NUMBERS = ImmutableSet.of(813, 907, 908, 909, 910);

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final int number = 907;
        final boolean b = NUMBERS.contains(number);
        System.out.println(b); // true
    }
}
```

`ImmutableSet` ensures no one adds something to `NUMBERS`

Answer (score 1):

Since your array is sorted, you can use [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29).

This allows you not to have to convert to a `List` first. Check the return code of this method: if it is positive, the element is in the array; if it is negative, it isn't:

```
int number = 907;
System.out.println(Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, number) >= 0);
```

Comment: Uhm, OK, I need to test; however, if this is a sorted array, my method will work for you. Deleting the irrelevant part.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code instead. This is just one of those times you've got to deal with Java's strongly typed quirks :)

```
import java.util.Arrays;

    public class Main {
        static Integer[] numbers = {813, 907, 908, 909, 910};

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer number = new Integer(907);

        boolean b = Arrays.asList(numbers).contains(number);
        System.out.println(b); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You did notice that your answer is exactly the same as mine?

Comment: Not really, object vs symbol... It's also a bit shorter

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a for loop going through the array and match each element with the one that you are looking for. Afterwards you can go from there.

For the reason why it isnt working is the same reason as others said before.