# For loop not running correctly

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, integer

When I execute this code the output is "140" which is "28*5" but it should be "150" which is "28+31+30+31+30" it should calculate the days between 2 months "feb" and "july"... So it means that the for loop isn't working correctly or what ? and why is that ! can you help me here ??
PS: I tried to change the j++ in the loop to j+1 but Android Studio Says"that's not a statement"

```
int[] pair = {1,3,5,7,8,10,12};
int[] impair = {4,6,9,11};
int x=0;
int j;
int year=2015;
int mm=2;
int month=7;
String msg="";
if (month>mm) {
    for (j = mm; j<month; j++){
        if (Arrays.asList(impair).contains(j)){
            x = 31 + x;
        }else if(Arrays.asList(pair).contains(j)){
            x = 30 + x;
        }else{
            if (year%4==0) {
                x= 29 + x;
            }else{
                x= 28 + x;
            }
        }
    }
    System.output.println(x);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and stepping through your program line by line?

Comment: now there's a brilliant idea !

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing that and even changed  a lot of things like 4 times but I couldn't fix it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are attempting to convert the `int[]` to a `List<Integer>` by calling `Arrays.asList`.  But that results in a `List<int[]>` of a single element (the original `int[]`), which doesn't contain any value of `j`.  The reason is given in [Arrays.asList() not working as it should?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467913/arrays-aslist-not-working-as-it-should) -- it's a generic method, and the type parameter must be a reference type.  `int[]` is a reference type (as all arrays are), but `int` isn't.

That is why the tests all fail and `28` is repeatedly chosen to be added.

Change the declared types of `pair` and `impair` from `int[]` to `Integer[]`, so that `Arrays.asList` will infer the type as `Integer` (a reference type) correctly.  Then the `contains` method will work as expected.  With this change I get `150`.

Comment: Nice. Also need to fix the incorrect test for a leap year: year%4==0 is incomplete. Should be something like: ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) || (year % 400 == 0)

Comment: Just a little more info - there is a obvious bug with pair / impair arrays and 31/30 instead of 30/31 days assignment.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the asList() requires a class object which is either a collection and Iterable. You could modify your code in the following way:-

```
Integer[] pair = {1,3,5,7,8,10,12};
Integer[] impair = {4,6,9,11};
int x=0;
int j;
int year=2015;
int mm=2;
int month=7;
String msg="";
if (month>mm) {
    for (j = mm; j<month; j++){
        if (Arrays.asList(impair).contains(new Integer(j))){
            x = 31 + x;
        }else if(Arrays.asList(pair).contains(new Integer(j))){
            x = 30 + x;
        }else{
            if (year%4==0) {
                x= 29 + x;
            }else{
                x= 28 + x;
            }
        }
    }
    System.output.println(x);
}
```

This should give you the correct output.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your loop never enters the first two if blocks as that is not how aslist(array).contains(element) works

[Java, Simplified check if int array contains int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020361/java-simplified-check-if-int-array-contains-int)

[Checking whether an element exist in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17510664/checking-whether-an-element-exist-in-an-array)