# Writing a toString function to return part of an array but not the whole thing

Tags: java

So basically I have the array
`int[] i = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};`

I want the toString method to return
`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` only.

How would I do this without creating a new array?

Comment: The `toString()` method of what class?

Comment: What is the logic to divide this return part?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis a class I'm making myself

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList(i).subList(0,5).toString()`

You can't override the `toString()` method for primitive arrays, so you have to wrap it

-- Note: --

Unfortunately, this will not compile for primitive int[] arrays (your example), only Object[] arrays.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java) for details

Comment: Added a note; Forgot one little detail

Comment: Yeah I just noticed that. The question offers a good way to fix that though so it's not a big deal.

Comment: I'm in two minds if this falls under *"creating a new array"* ... +1 none the less...

Comment: Oh yeah that's true because it changes it to a list

Comment: There's no copying going on here - `Arrays.asList`, `List.subList`, and `Ints.asList` (from the link) are all merely *views*, lazily-computed.  So I don't think it does fall under "*creating a new array*"

Comment: A *view* is a way of taking one object and disguising it as another - for example, disguising an `int[]` as a `List<Integer>`.  Given the underlying `int[]`, one can define a wrapper class that implements `List<Integer>`, and define the access methods appropriately.  The wrapper merely references the `int[]` object, so the memory overhead is constant - nothing new is created, just a light-weight 'converter', so to speak, to translate from `List<Integer>` speak to `int[]` speak

Answer (score 2):

Given the fact that you only need to return a `String`, simply start with a `StringBuilder` and loop over the range...

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(12);
for (int index = 0; index < Math.min(5, i.length); index++) {
    if (sb.length() > 0) {
        sb.append(", ");
    }
    sb.append(i[index]);
}
sb.insert(0, "[");
sb.append("]");

return sb.toString();
```

Comment: perfect answer, because no new array is created in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Arrays.copyOf` method to implement the function you wanted.

```
    int[] i = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

    //Copy first 5 elements
    int[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(i, 5);

    //Print [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    System.out.print(Arrays.toString(copy));
```

Or just Print it using the following code:

**`System.out.print(Arrays.toString(Arrays.copyOf(i, 5)));`**

It prints out [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] in console.

Source code of copyOf method is as follows: (JDK 1.6)

```
/**
 * Copies the specified array, truncating or padding with zeros (if necessary)
 * so the copy has the specified length.  For all indices that are
 * valid in both the original array and the copy, the two arrays will
 * contain identical values.  For any indices that are valid in the
 * copy but not the original, the copy will contain <tt>0</tt>.
 * Such indices will exist if and only if the specified length
 * is greater than that of the original array.
 *
 * @param original the array to be copied
 * @param newLength the length of the copy to be returned
 * @return a copy of the original array, truncated or padded with zeros
 *     to obtain the specified length
 * @throws NegativeArraySizeException if <tt>newLength</tt> is negative
 * @throws NullPointerException if <tt>original</tt> is null
 * @since 1.6
 */
public static int[] copyOf(int[] original, int newLength) {
    int[] copy = new int[newLength];
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to create a new array for memory conservation purposes.