# Using parseInt to convert String to Integer returns NPE

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to convert a String to an Integer using the `Integer.parseInt()` method as follows:

```
public Job[] convertStringListToIntegerList(
            Integer noOfJobs, List<String> numbersListAsStrings) {
        Job[] integerList = new Job[noOfJobs];
        int i = 0;
        for (String s : numbersListAsStrings) {
            String[] jobWeightLength = s.split(" ");
            integerList[i].weight = Integer.parseInt(jobWeightLength[0]);
            integerList[i].length = Integer.parseInt(jobWeightLength[1]);
            i++;
        }
        return integerList;
    }
```

Here `Job` is defined as follows:

```
public class Job {
    Integer length;
    Integer weight;
    Integer difference;
    Float ratio;
}
```

I have referred to this question:

- [How to convert int[] to List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)

However, as you can see the variable I am using to store the result of `Integer.parseInt()` is an `Integer`, not an `int` and yet getting a `NullPointerException` at:

```
integerList[i].weight = Integer.parseInt(jobWeightLength[0]);
```

Can you please point me as to what's going wrong here?

Comment: I never thought enhanced for loops would result in index counters. Note that this method will fail is your list is bigger than noOfJobs.

Comment: @Hannes: I am pretty sure that the length of the list is equal to `noOfJobs`. However, is there a better method to make sure the method does not fail even if this is violated?

Comment: You can use `int length = Math.min(noOfJobs, numbersListAsString);` to be sure, then use the determined length to size the job array and iterate through the list i = 0; i < length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an instance of the Job class before you can assign to its fields

```
    for (String s : numbersListAsStrings) {
        String[] jobWeightLength = s.split(" ");
        integerList[i] = new Job();
        // ...
```

Comment: I am creating an array of `Job` here: `Job[] integerList = new Job[noOfJobs];`. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @Jobin No, arrays are __initialized__ with `null` references.

Comment: @Jobin `new Job[noOfJobs]` creates the array but all it's elements will be null - you have to create the individual Job instances separately.

Comment: Thanks! I am beginner and this was frustrating. Thanks for saving my day! :)

Answer (score 2):

Try following loop instead the one you have.

```
for (String s : numbersListAsStrings) {
        String[] jobWeightLength = s.split(" ");
        integerList[i]=new Job();
        integerList[i].weight = Integer.parseInt(jobWeightLength[0]);
        integerList[i].length = Integer.parseInt(jobWeightLength[1]);
        i++;
    }
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks! @IanRoberts answered a little earlier, +1 though- this was exactly what was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

`integerList[i]` is null. `integerList[i].weight` references the `weight` field of a `null` `Job`. You should fill `integerList` with `new Job()` objects before using it.

see:

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfJobs; i++)
    integerList[i] = new Job();
```

Comment: Thanks, @IanRoberts answered a little earlier, +1 though, this was exactly what was wrong. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public Job[] convertStringListToIntegerList(
        Integer noOfJobs, List<String> numbersListAsStrings) {
    int size = Math.min(noOfJobs, numbersListAsStrings.length());
    Job[] integerList = new Job[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String[] jobWeightLength = numbersListAsStrings.get(i).split(" ");
        integerList[i] = new Job();
        integerList[i].weight = Integer.parseInt(jobWeightLength[0]);
        integerList[i].length = Integer.parseInt(jobWeightLength[1]);
    }
    return integerList;
}
```