# java primitive array to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json, arrays

I'm trying convert java primitive array to JSONArray, but I have strange behaviour.My code below.

```
long [] array = new long[]{1, 2, 3};
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(array));
jsonArray.toString();
```

output is `["[J@532372dc"]`

Why Do I get this output? I want to get output like this `[1, 2, 3]`

Comment: `new JSONArray(array)` is sufficient to supply a (primitive) array to the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**problem:**

```
Arrays.asList(array)
```

You cant transform an array of primitive types to Collections that it needs to be an array of Objects type. Since `asList` expects a `T...` note that it needs to be an object.

why is it working?

That is because upon passing it in the parameter it will **autoBox** it since array are type object.

**solution:**

You need to change it to its wrapper class, and use it as an array.

**sample:**

```
Long[] array = new Long[]{1L, 2L, 3L};
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(array));
jsonArray.toString();
```

**result:**

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: You will need to cast the values of `array` to `long` or else it will give `Type mismatch: cannot convert from int to Long`

Comment: @Apoorv no need I can just directly add a modifier on it.

Comment: Yes you can do it either way.

Comment: About autoboxing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java

Comment: How we can do reverse.? like i have have String[] and i want to convert it to json format like {'0','1','2'}.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is just to convert a primitive integer array to a `JSONArray`, cut the long story short.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(longArray).get(0));
```

* *You will need a try/catch block*