# Android - Reading an array from intent and adding it to JsonObject

Tags: android, json

In one of my libraries say libA, I am reading a JsonArray (with string values in it) from JsonObject and converting it to String[] before adding it to an intent as extra and then I pass down that intent to another activity say activityA. I am reading from intent in activityA and creating a JsonObject out of it for use later, but am not able to add an array directly to a JsonObject.

***Code in libA:***

```
JsonObject metadata; // This has the JsonArray in it.
final String[] bookIdsArray = new Gson().fromJson(metadata.get("bookIds") , String[].class);
testIntent.putExtra("bookIds", bookIdsArray);
```

***Code in activityA:***

```
final JsonObject activityMetadata = new JsonObject();
activityMetadata.addProperty("bookIds", String.valueOf(intent.getStringArrayExtra("bookIds")));
```

addProperty method of JsonObject only accepts String, Number, Boolean or Character and another method called 'add' only accepts JsonElement. How can I directly add array to it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java primitive array to JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25258529/java-primitive-array-to-jsonarray)

Comment: I want to add an array in JsonObject. The link is for converting array in JsonArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JsonObject method `add(String property, JsonElement value)` as `JsonArray` extends `JsonElement`.

```
String[] idsFromIntent = intent.getStringArrayExtra("bookIds");
JsonArray bookIds = new JsonArray();
    for (String id : idsFromIntent) {
        bookIds.add(id);
    }
activityMetadata.add("bookIds", bookIds);
```