# java : Understanding Arrays.asList(T...array) method for primitive types

Tags: java, arrays, list, autoboxing

I wrote following code and was surprised to see the output:

```
    Integer a = 211;
    int b = 211;

    int[] array = {210,211,212};

    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(a));
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(b));
```

Output:

```
false
false
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java) question and some other questions linked to it and learned that `asList` method doesn't Autobox stuffs. I checked the returned type in eclipse javadoc preview:

[image]

I couldn't quite understand this return type. `int[]` is an object and not a primitive so its fine. I'm sure that I'm not getting `List<Integer>` (something which I expected) but I'm not sure how to use the thing which is being returned. My questions are:

  1. How exactly do I expect that list methods will work when I'm expecting an List of Integer and getting a List of int[] ?

  2. In case of Strings the return type is List of String and not List of String[]. What sort of implementation differences are there?

  3. What good is this method for primitives if things are so uncertain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are obviously 3 questions here so lets tackle them one by one:

> 1. How exactly do I expect that list methods will work when I'm expecting an List of Integer and getting a List of int[] ?

Well, `List` methods will work exactly as expected, a `List<T>` is a list of types `T`. Here `T` is an `int[]` so a `List<int[]>` will contains arrays as each element:

```
[{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {1, 6}]
```

So `get(i)` will return the `ith` element. In the case of `Arrays.asList` the `List` contains a single element, namely the `int[]` so:

```
int[] array = {210,211,212};
List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Will be

```
[{210, 211, 212}]
```

And so

```
list.get(0)[0] == 210
```

> In case of Strings the return type is List of String and not List of String[]. What sort of implementation differences are there?

`String` is an `Object`, **not** a primitive type. The difference follows from that.

> 3. What good is this method for primitives if things are so uncertain?

Things are not *uncertain*.  This method results in **defined** and **predictable** behaviour.  It's just not very useful for primitives.  This is (yet another) side effect of combining Java's type system with generics.

Note with Java 8 the conversion of an `int[]` to a `List<Integer>` is very simple:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(array).
        boxed().
        collect(toList());
```

Comment: Thanks for the new java 8 example

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting a Lit or a List (which can't be), you're getting a List of arrays of integer.

So your list does not contain 211, it contains an array that then contains 211.

The array is not "unrolled" into the list, it is added "as is" to a newly created list.

So :

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(array)); // Will return true
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(a).contains(a)); // Will return true
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because `Arrays.asList()` is a [variadic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) generic function. Change this,

```
int[] array = {210,211,212};
```

to

```
Integer[] array = { 210, 211, 212 };
```

And the output will be `true` and `true`.

Answer (score 3):

Arrays.asList takes objects as params. Since int[] is an object, you get the List.
If you want a list of integers you should do Arrays.asList(211,212,213).

Answer (score 1):

```
int[] array = {210,211,212};

Arrays.asList(array)
```

is equal to

```
List<int[]> asList = Arrays.asList(array);
```

Change

`int[] array = {210,211,212};` to `Integer[] array = {210,211,212};` and it will work.
 and its equals to `List<Integer> asList = Arrays.asList(array);`