# Compile error while converting array to Set in java

Tags: java, arrays, set

I was trying to convert `int` array to `Set<Integer>`.

```
int[] arr = {5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3};
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

But the compiler doesn't accept the above code. It says: "The constructor HashSet(List) is undefined." Well, I thought that `int` should be autoboxed.

I slightly modified the code, change `int` to `String`:

```
String[] arr = {"hello", "world"};
Set<String> s = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

This code works okay.

I tried the following, change `int` to `Integer`:

```
Integer[] arr = {5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3};
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

This is passed the compilation.

My question is: **why doesn't java compiler accept the first code?**

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890806/java-understanding-arrays-aslistt-array-method-for-primitive-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the call to `Arrays.asList(arr)`.  It has gotten confused by the use of a primitive array.  Java treats primitives and objects differently.

asList only knows about arrays of objects, and in your case it is treating the entire array as a single element.  That is, `asList(arr)` is returning `Set<int[]>`, such that the following is true:

```
Set<int[]> s = new HashSet<Integer>(ints);
```

Which is not what you meant.

There is no auto boxing of primitive arrays in Java.  The quickest fix is to use Integer rather than int for the input array:

```
Integer[] arr = {5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3};   // java supports autoboxing when declaring an array 
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

otherwise you will have to iterate and add the elements yourself.

```
int[] arr = {5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3};
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>();        
for ( int v : arr ) {
    s.add(v);  // autoboxing of a single int is supported by Java, and happens here
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] arr = {5, 2, 7, 2, 4, 7, 8, 2, 3};
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(arr));
```

Because your `Set` is type `Integer`(Object) and `array` is type `int`(primitive).

Read [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

```
Arrays.asList() // takes in put as Generics
```

Generics in `Java` is not applicable to `primitive` types as in `int`. That's why you are getting this error.

Comment: `Arrays.asList(arr)` returns a list of `Integer`'s. Collections wont support primitives.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Issue is not with return type, issue in input type in `asList()`

Comment: @TheLostMind Issue is not with return type, issue in input type in `asList()`

Answer (score 1):

In java Containers want "Objects" and primitives don't derive from Object. Generics allow you to pretend there is no wrapper, but you still pay the performance price of boxing. This is IMPORTANT to many programmers.

List list; That is also a reason why there are wrapper classes for primitive types:

```
int -> Integer

boolean -> Boolean

double -> Double

byte -> Byte etc...
```