# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when accessing List<int[]>

Tags: java

Why am I getting `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ERRO` while executing the following code?

```
int[] things={11,22,33,44};
List<int[]>Listdata = Arrays.asList(things);
int[] n=Listdata.get(1);
System.out.println(n[1]);
```

It works fine if i put `get(0)`

Comment: You only put one array in your List, so why would you expect to have one at the second index?

Comment: @SolomonPByer:  You most certainly can have a `List<int[]>`.  It's binding the generic type `T` to an `int[]` instead.

Comment: @DebojitPaul What do you think `List<int[]>` is ? If you can answer this question, you can answer why your code doesn't work.

Comment: Then how to access specific data from a list at a time.What are the other methods.

Comment: Clarification on @ZouZou's first comment: Array and (standard) list indexing starts at `0`, not `1`. You have **1** object (of type `int[]`) in your list. Its index is `0`. Index `1` is out of bounds of the data structure.

Answer (score 2):

An `int[]` array maps most naturally to a `List<Integer>`. Unfortunately, [there is no built-in way to convert directly from an `int` array to an `Integer` list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java), due to the boxing that is required. You'll have to build the `List` manually.

```
int[] things = {11, 22, 33, 44};

List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i: things) {
    list.add(i);
}

int n = list.get(1);
System.out.println(n);
```

The excellent [Guava library](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#asList%28int...%29) from Google has a convenience method you could use, if you're willing to rely on a third-party library call.

```
int[] things = {11, 22, 33, 44};
List<Integer> list = Ints.asList(things);
int n = list.get(1);
System.out.println(n);
```

Or if your goal is simply to get a `List` of numbers, you could skip the intermediate array.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(11, 22, 33, 44);
```

Comment: `List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(things).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());` would also do the trick with Java 8!

Comment: Or if you don't mind autoboxing, `Integer[] things = {11, 22, 33, 44};` then `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(things);`.