# Android Java String Array using ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, android, arrays, string, arraylist

I am populating JSON parsed data into Dialog, like this:

```
String[] colors = new String[] {cArrayList.toString()};
Log.d("colors::-", Arrays.toString(colors));
```

**GETTING**

[image]

**EXPECTED**

[image]

Comment: `String[] colors = new String[]{ cArrayList.size() };` What are you attempting to do here? Create an array of Strings of that size or put the size of that arraylist as the first element in the colors array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your requirement you can do following if your cArrayList is ArrayList

```
String[] colors = new String[cArrayList.size()] ;
for(int i=0;i<cArrayList.size();i++)
{
  colors[i]=cArrayList.get(i);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the more concise and faster approach:

```
String[] colors = cArrayList.toArray(new String[cArrayList.size()]);
```

Comment: getting NPE at this line checkedColors[which] = isChecked; check this: http://pastebin.com/81PBd4Rd

Comment: where you defining checkedColors i dint see initialization of checkedColors

Comment: global boolean[] checkedColors = null; @Pavan check this : http://pastebin.com/81PBd4Rd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90093/discussion-between-oreo-and-pavan).

Answer (score 0):

Like in Core Java you convert `int[]` to `List<Integer>` same as the code shows below:

```
    int[] ints = {100,1000,10000};
    List<Integer> ls = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int index = 0; index < ints.length; index++)
    {
        ls.add(ints[index]);
    }
```

View reference [How to convert int[] into List in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

To convert your integer value to a string use:

```
String.valueOf(insert your integer value here);
```

Comment: It convert your integer value to string