# Converting from int array to Integer arraylist in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a problem in converting from Array to ArrayList

```
public class one 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
int y[]={12,25,38,46};
two p=new two();
p.setLocations(y);
}
}


import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;   

public class two 
{
    ArrayList<Integer> data_array=new ArrayList<Integer>();


void setLocations(int locations[])
{
        ArrayList<Integer> locations_arraylist=new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(locations));
        data_array=locations_arraylist;
    for(int i=0;i<data_array.size();i++)
        System.out.println("data_array["+i+"]="+data_array.get(i));
}
}
```

In the below line

```
ArrayList<Integer> locations_arraylist=new  ArrayList(Arrays.asList(locations));
//Copying from array to ArrayList-Its converting,Please suggest
```

Comment: What is `locations`: array of `int` **or** `ArrayList<Integer>`?  Please make up your mind.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad "locations" is an array of int,I needed to convert locations from int into ArrayList<Integer>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert int\[\] into List<Integer> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `int[]` is quite different from a `List<Integer>`. For example, an `Integer` has an identity as well as a value. There is no very simple way to do the conversion.

The following way works with Java 8.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
List<Integer> list = IntStream.of(array).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

The following way works in earlier versions.

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int a : array)
    list.add(a);
```

If you pass an `int[]` to `Arrays.asList` you get a `List<int[]>`, not a `List<Integer>`.

Comment: refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23548085/3048967). It contains additional details.

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the interface `List` for members/variables and use the `ArrayList` constructor. Also `ArrayList` without the brackets indicates the raw type instead of instead of the generic.

If you would like to avoid a for loop that will copy the values from array to `List`, there are 2 solutions :

1. Guava  (put on top `import com.google.common.primitives.Ints;`)

   ```
   List<Integer> locations_arraylist = Ints.asList(locations);
   ```
2. pass the values to `Arrays.asList()` directly

   ```
   List<Integer> locations_arraylist = Arrays.asList(12, 25, 38, 46);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

> You can try this:

replace `int y[]={12,25,38,46};` to `Integer y[] = {12, 25, 38, 46};`
  No need of this line as well
 `ArrayList<Integer> data_array = new ArrayList<Integer>();`
**You can use for-each loop for print the array :**

```
int i=0;
        for (Integer locations_arraylist1 : locations_arraylist) {
             System.out.println("data_array[" + i + "]=" + locations_arraylist1);
             i++;
        }
```

Comment: `setLocations(Integer locations[])` should be an Integer array parameter as well .

Comment: i need to extend my class and needed to perform add and remove options in future.

Comment: Then Its better to go with Paul Boddington 's answer . He has used a list for his solution there. I was just trying to make minimal fixes and make ur code work . :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int[] arrayInt = new int[]{1, 2, 3};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(ArrayUtils.toObject(arrayInt));
```