# Getting a List<Integer> from a resource array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have a string-array resource with integers.

```
<string-array name="navChildRatings">
    <item>12</item>
    <item>12</item>
    <item>17</item>
    <item>123</item>
    <item>8</item>

</string-array>
```

My goal is to have them into a list of type `List<Integer>`
As a first step I know they can be assigned into an integer array by:

```
int[] ratings = Arrays.asList(getResources().getIntArray(R.array.navChildRatings));
```

I am trying to avoid looping through the array of integers (ints) and having to add one by one to the List of Integers (java.lang.Integer).

1. Is there a direct way to get the string-array into a `List<Integer>`?
   or, alternatively
2. Is there a direct way to assign the `int[]` array to a `List<Integer>`?

**Note**: My motivation is purely to have a more elegant code. I know how to do it by looping the array. But, for example, in the case of Strings it works if you  assign it directly:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.navChildNames));
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be an `<integer-array>`?

Comment: Maybe you are right, I will test it and let you know.

Comment: It still won't get your code to work the way you want but at least you won't have to parse the strings into Integers. You will have to use a for loop if you need a `List<Integer>` from the int[]. To keep it elegant you can write your own helper method that takes an int[] and returns a `List<Integer>` so you only have to write the loop once.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java

Comment: @MarcoAltieri Not a duplicate. I am trying to avoid looping, which is not addressed in that question.

Comment: Ok. I meant that there is already an answer that says that is not possible

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan You were right on both your comments, thanks. Still I will have to do that helper thing.

Comment: Is there a reason you need a `List<Integer>` instead of an `int[]`? I ask because if the default `List` implementation returned by `asList()` is in fact an `ArrayList`, then you aren't actually gaining anything (since `ArrayList` is backed by an array anyway). In fact, you may lose some performance/memory because all your ints now have to be boxed.

Comment: @Karakuri I need the List<> to pass to on  to a library method that requires List<Integer>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unofortunately this is impossible since [asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) is not handling boxing (wrapping primitive) and will not create objects automatically.

If you want to keep code elegant and using Java8 you can easily create [lambda](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) to do it as one-liner

if you do not use Java8 just create a simple method to convert **int[]** to **List**

```
    ArrayList<Integer> getList(int[] a)
    {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i : a)
            l.add( new Integer(i) );

        return l;
    }
```

and then

```
    List<Integer> items = getList(ratings);
```

Comment: Is this something I can do for Android java? I am not sure it is Java8

Comment: It isn't, Android uses Java 7

Comment: if you are using this very often just create a simple method to convert int[] array