# Changing Array to ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to find duplicate element in an array. I have already solved it using traversing the array. But now i want to convert array to arraylist and use contains keyword of arraylist.

I am not able to convert array to arraylist and use the contains keyword. please look in following code:

```
public void findDuplicate2() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 7, 5 };
    ArrayList<int[]> arrlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (arrlist.contains(arr[i]))
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        else
            System.out.println("no duplicate" + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your compile error.

Comment: is `len` used in for initalization block an instance variable?

Comment: Do you want an `ArrayList<int[]>`? I think you prefer `ArrayList<Integer>`.

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention that len variable is length of array.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code:

- You are creating an `ArrayList<int[]>`, that is, an array list of arrays of `int`. This list contains one array, namely the one you started out from. I don’t think this was what you intended. My guess is you wanted an `ArrayList<Integer>` containing the numbers from the array. khelwood’s link should help you out.
- You haven’t declared `i` nor `len`. I suggest you use `for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)`.
- `arrlist.contains(arr[i])` always returns `false` since a list of arrays cannot contain a number (the numbers inside the array are not searched). It’s a design problem with `ArrayList` that you can ask for whether it contains an element of the wrong type (there are historical reasons for this). If you change the arraylist to `ArrayList<Integer>` as I suggested above, it will work, though.
- Once you get the above to work, `arrlist.contains(arr[i])` will always return `true` since each number from the array will be in the array list, also the ones that are not duplicates.

Comment: Thanks,                                                                                                                        1. Yes true I wanted to create arraylist of integer which will have same element as in array.  2. I changed the element to integer before as well but i am getting compile time error (Type mismatch: cannot convert from ArrayList<int[]> to ArrayList<Integer>) 3. len  is length of array which i had  declared where array was declared. while posting here i forgot to copy that. Need help with above compile time error

Comment: `Arrays.asList()` does not work with an array of primitives (like `int`s). This is the reason for your compile time error. To convert your array of `int` to `ArrayList<Integer>` you may either see [How to convert int[\] into List<Integer> in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java) (as has been mentioned) or use `ArrayList<Integer> arrlist = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(arr).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));` (requires Java 8).

Comment: This solved my problem.

Comment: hey Ole V.V what if i have array of string in this case? suppose  String arr = "somerandom". Can i change this to arraylist?

Comment: Of course you can. How? That depends on whether you mean a `String` or an array (`String[]`), and the element type you want in your `ArrayList`. Please post a new question and spell out your requirements and also what you have tried and how it failed. I promise I will take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Here your arrlist variable is of type int[]. Here your arrlist size is 1(the entire input array as single entry).

So, you can only check the existence of any integer array in the list by using contains method of arrlist. **if (arrlist.contains(arr))** //returns true in your case

Comment: if (arrlist.contains(arr)) will always return true. How can i create an arraylist (integer type ) with same element which are present in array?

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to find dublicates is this one:

```
public void findDuplicate2(){
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,3,7,5};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        boolean dublicate = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if(arr[i] == arr[j] && i != j){
                System.out.println(arr[i]);
                dublicate = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!dublicate)
            System.out.println("No dublicate " + arr[i]);
    }
}
```

In your code the arraylist contains one element, the array arr. You can check this with

```
System.out.println(arrlist.get(0));
System.out.println(arrlist.get(1));
```

The right way would be to transfer each element of arr to arraylist...

Comment: This i have already done. I wanted using arraylist. Thanks :)