# Compare int[] with once Integer

Tags: java, int, compare

I have table of `int[]`. I have for loop with every user and I do:

```
int[] ids = (values) 
for (User user : listAfterProcessing) {
    if (user.getId().equals(ids)) { ... } 
}
```

They didnt work, Although the user id is in this table...
Thanks for help :)

Comment: what does `getId()` return?, i'm  guessing an `int`

Comment: `ids` is an array, `user.getId()` probably returns an int, so if you compare these two it always returns `false`

Comment: getId() return Integer

Comment: [How can I test if an array contains a certain value?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1128723)

Answer (score 3):

You are checking whether the result of `getId()` equals the entire array `ids`, which is by default a comparison to the array's hashcode.

According to an answer in this question: [How to convert int[] into List<Integer> in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java)

> there is no quick way to convert.

The solution with Arrays.asList(), which I suggested in the first version of my answer, doesn't work here, sorry.

Comment: When I try this: if (Arrays.asList(ids).contains(user.getId())) this didnt work :(

Comment: you can do `List<Integer> tempList = Arrays.stream(ids) .boxed() .collect(Collectors.toList());` before the loop and then change the condition to `if (tempList.contains(user.getId()))`

Comment: or change the condition to `if(Arrays.stream(ids).anyMatch(id -> id == user.getId()))`, or do another loop inside the current one looping over the array of ids and then do your comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing an `int` array to a single `Integer` will not get you the result you want. You could go through the whole array and test every cell for the value, or you could keep the array sorted and do a binary search:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

Arrays.sort(ids);
if(Arrays.binarySearch(ids, user.getId().intValue()) >= 0) {}
```