# Passing ArrayList to TreeSet constructor

Tags: java, treeset

When I am passing an ArrayList to TreeSet constructor, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [I cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
    at java.util.TreeMap.compare(TreeMap.java:1294)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(TreeMap.java:538)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(TreeSet.java:255)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(AbstractCollection.java:344)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(TreeSet.java:312)
    at java.util.TreeSet.<init>(TreeSet.java:160)
    at jay.week1.MaxPairwiseProduct.getMaxPairwiseProduct(MaxPairwiseProduct.java:8)
    at jay.week1.MaxPairwiseProduct.main(MaxPairwiseProduct.java:17)
```

I am getting the above error at this line :

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(numbers));
```

This is the full program:

```
import java.util.*;


public class MaxPairwiseProduct {
static int getMaxPairwiseProduct(int[] numbers) {
    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(numbers));
    int max1 = set.pollLast();
    int max2 = set.pollLast();
    int result = max1 * max2;
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3};
    System.out.println(getMaxPairwiseProduct(numbers));
}

}
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please include the actual failing code.

Comment: It is failing at TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet(Arrays.asList(numbers));

Comment: change `int[] number` to `Integer [] number`.

Comment: Arrays.asList of an integer array does not automatically box primitives to integer object... You will be better off by using a loop to create a list of Integer objects and change your Treeset implementation to
`TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>(array list containing the integer array elements);`

Comment: You're missing the generic operator in `new TreeSet<>(...)`, and you're getting a compiler warning about it. Add that, and it may be able to deduce what's needed

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073919/how-to-convert-int-into-listinteger-in-java

Answer (score 2):

What Arrays.asList() actually returning is list of int array.

```
List<int[]> list = Arrays.asList(numbers);
```

You need to do the following.

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = Arrays.stream(number).boxed()
.collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

Answer (score 1):

It is failing to do that because you can't have a `TreeSet<int>`, only a `TreeSet<Integer>`.

Because you did not specify a generic type for `TreeSet`, `Arrays.asList` tries to create a `List<int[]>`, which it succeeds. Why a `int[]`? You might ask. This is because `int` cannot be a generic type, so the generic parameter of `asList` is inferred to be `int[]`, which can be a generic type. But then this list goes into `TreeSet`'s constructor and `TreeSet` discovers that this is not a list of `Integer`s, throwing an exception.

To fix this, you either change the parameter type from `int[]` to `Integer[]`, or convert the `int[]` to a `Integer[]` before passing it into `Arrays.asList`.

```
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>(Arrays.stream(numbers).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Comment: This is all correct but doesn't really explain that the inferred type for the raw `TreeSet` is `TreeSet<int[]>`.